# How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?

Tags: performance

What are your tips for improving overall system performance on ubuntu? Inspired by this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2099) I realized that some default settings may be rather conservative on Ubuntu and that it's possible to tweak it with little or no risk if you wish to make it faster.

This is not meant to be application specific (e.g. make firefox load pages faster), but system wide.

Preferably 1 tip per answer, with enough detail for people to implement it.

A couple of mine would be:

- Install [Preload](http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/drastically-speed-up-your-linux-system-with-preload/) (via Software Center or `sudo apt-get install preload`);
- Change [Swappiness](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) value - "which controls the degree to which the kernel prefers to swap when it tries to free memory";

What are yours?

PS: Since this is not intended to have a unique answer but rather, several useful tips, I'm making this community wiki out-of-the-box.

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention how effective your tip is: how much of an improvement did you **notice**, or even better, **measure**?

Comment: I have not found any evidence that changing the swappiness has any positive effect. It might give a temporary feeling of performance increase, that seems to subside quite fast. I have not seen any concrete evidence in form of benchmarks that would proof the effectiveness of changing the swapiness parameter

Comment: I doubt it has any noticeable performance impact. The ttys used hardly any memory, nor would there be any significant cpu usage.

Comment: Isn't "premature optimization the root of all evil"? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes)

Comment: @Alejandro that quote assumes that you've done it as well as you could in the first place.

Comment: Aren't a lot of these tips going to be hardware dependent? eg. optimal swapiness is going to depend on bus speeds, hard drive speed, and ram.

Comment: @Alejandro what makes this premature, and when will it become mature? Also, you do realise you're quoting from an essay about the importance of striving to make software behave quickly that only mentions ill-considered attempts at optimisation to then point out that optimisation remains important (and giving an example of a 12% speed increase in a function), yes?

Comment: If anyone is interested, I cooked up a [bash script for Ubuntu Raring](https://gist.github.com/alixaxel/5605638#comment-832059) that automates most of the stuff suggested here, I noticed a huge improvement on my old netbook with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Will this preload thing provide a significant benefit when the system is running from an SSD?

Comment: The second link (the one regarding Preload) doesn't seems to work. It's loading and loading and loading, and nothing shows up in the browser, just a blank page which keeps loading. (Hm! Funny! The page is about Preload app and it's...  (pre)loading! )

Comment: Currently, [there is no apps named "Preload" on the Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=preload). However, it could be installed using `apt`.

Answer (score 187):

**If you are "the average Joe"**, then just don't do anything. Don't fiddle with programs or settings which you don't understand. Don't follow tips posted on the Internet how to improve the performance of your system by compiling some software yourself or by installing a selfmade kernel.

Some of those tips may give you minor performance improvements indeed, but some of them will also give you a real headache, if you changed the wrong setting, disabled the wrong service, installed the wrong driver etc.

Therefore just be happy about your nicely running system. And BTW: Why would you need those 5 percent performance improvements? It will not lead to typing your office documents faster or editing your holiday photos in half the time.

*And just to be clear: If you are not the average Joe, but a developer/hardcore gamer/... needing any cycle you can get, you are not the target of this comment...*

Comment: Tweaking settings and compiling your own kernel and software is a great way to learn. I think it should be encouraged, as long as people know that when they break things badly, they may need to re-install their OS.

Comment: Only people that really want to understand how the kernel works should consider compiling your own kernel. For most people, they should even know a "kernel" exists. 

Stick with a stock kernel and you can take advantage of the regular software updates.

Comment: @bananeweizen: I was about to yell at you something like "who do you think you are?" or some other kindergarten-ish insult: luckily I read more than once your answer...if I could I'd upvote it hundreds times.

Comment: @Brad, ah how the times have changed :) When I started with Linux we _had_ to compile our own kernel since it was before dynamic modules were implemented.  I don't miss it though!

Comment: @Nerdfest That is a good point, my most important teacher in the linux-world have no doubt been the Gentoo manual... I never really got a working GUI, but I did learn a lot about how a basic linux install works! And that is practically the same on all the distro's

Comment: @Nerdfest great answer, and to add to it this is what VM's are for.  Get a stable OS (Ubuntu 10.04, Fedora 13, Something) and then VirtualBox and play with VMs!

Comment: @Bananeweizen I don't really think this question was aimed at 'developers and hardcore gamers,' so I downvoted you.

Comment: I'm playing around with performance tweaks right now precisely for what I'm learning from them. That said there are two cases where I always want to tweak with Windows, and I'm having the same attitude with Ubuntu: 1. A system's so slow that every little helps. 2. A system's so fast that I can't help but wonder what it can be cranked up to! Middling systems I leave alone :)
That said, a definite +1

Comment: Do cleaning utilities improve system-performance?

Comment: As a developer, gamer, hacker, the opportunity to learn is great when I want to take advantage of it.  But most of the time I want a reliable system that just works.  The dark side of "learning" is cognitive overload and spending several hours of troubleshooting and trial and error for a 5% performance boost is clinically insane IMO considering that such knowledge will become obsolete in six month's time anyhow.

Answer (score 105):

Disable automatic startup of any services that are not needed (or even remove the package completely).

A lot of packages start up services automatically. These services then use memory and CPU even they are hardly ever used. It is better in this case, to stop those services, or take them out of autostart, and start them up only if they are needed.

To remove applications from starting up on 10.04,go to *System > Preferences > Startup Applications* (may be slightly different on other versions)

On 12.04, you can go select the startup applications by clicking on the [Dash Icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements/62842#62842). Then, type startup and select "startup applications".

[image]

And just unmark the apps you don't need. But **be sure** about it, don't just remove apps you don't know. If you are not sure about one, leave it that way. A google search or new question here about specific programs will help.

Comment: Good one! simple and effective. I personally disable bluetooth related stuff, since my notebook doesn't have it.

Comment: Could you explain / add a link explaining how to view and disable/enable services under Ubuntu.

Comment: For Kubuntu/KDE users, the equivalent is: Start Menu Button -> System Settings -> System Administration -> Startup and Shutdown.  There are two sections, one for 'Autostart' and one for 'Service Manager' (for long running daemons) and you may both start-stop services as well as making sure they don't start as a part of the standard boot sequence.

Answer (score 76):

> #### [Disclaimer] Administer the following at your own risk.

[Tushar Neupaney](http://linuxfanatic.wordpress.com/author/infobatica/) gives this advices [here](http://linuxfanatic.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/make-your-linux-box-blazing-fast/):

**1. Use lighter applications (Replace your default applications with them)**

- Gedit >> Mousepad
- Picture viewer (EOG …) >> Gpicview
- Network Manager >> Wicd
- Evince >> epdfview

**2. Decrease Swappiness**

- `sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`

  Edit: vm.swappiness=10

**<s>3.  For dual cores (Use Concurrency)</s>**

- `sudo vim /etc/init.d/rc`

  Edit: CONCURRENCY=shell

  *shell* option is now obsolete. Default value is *makefile* and *shell* is by 2010-05-14 an alias for *makefile*.

**4. Clean up apt cache at /var/cache/apt/archives and unneccessary apt-sources list in /etc/apt/sources.list**

- `sudo apt-get autoclean`

**5. Install BUM (Boot Up manager)**

- `sudo apt-get install bum`

  Remove unnecessary applications and services from startup

**6. Remove some unnecessary TTY’s**

- `sudo vim /etc/default/console-setup`

  Edit: ACTIVE_CONSOLES=”/dev/tty[1-3]“

  Note: goto `/etc/init/` and change the tty’s files that you ***DO NOT*** want. Edit them and comment lines starting with “start on runlevel”. So, in this case, you’ll comment the start line in "tty4.conf" to "tty6.conf" files.

**<s>7. Install Prelink</s>**

- `sudo apt-get install prelink`
- `sudo vim /etc/default/prelink`

  Edit: PRELINKING=Yes
- `sudo /etc/cron.daily/prelink`

  Actually, Prelink is **useless** since Feisty Fawn (because Ubuntu uses a very effective runtime linker now). In addition, it's intrusive - it directly modifies the executables and ultimately can break them. **DO NOT** do it.

**8. Install Preload**

- `sudo apt-get install preload`

**9. Get rid of kinit if you don’t use hibernate and sleep functions.**

- `sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

  Edit: Comment (Put # in front of) RESUME=XXXX…………………….

Comment: This provides no information as to why we should follow your advice. Some context and benchmarks please.

Comment: I've edited to add the asked 'context' ;-)

Comment: I was trying number 3 and the comments above the line to change listed the valid options and 'shell' was not one of them.  Is this answer old?  Did the comment not tell me all the options?

Comment: I tried number 3 as well despite that "shell" option was not mentioned as valid one. After edit booting took twice longer than when concurrency was set to "none". So I went back to orginal setting.

Comment: `sed -i -r '1s/(^[^#])/#\1/g' /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` one line but only add comment if do not exist - good do add in script :)

Comment: As for #3: "Valid options are 'none' and 'makefile'.  Obsolete options used earlier are 'shell' and 'startpar'.  The obsolete options are aliases for 'makefile' since 2010-05-14.  The default since the same date is 'makefile', as the init.d scripts in Debian now include dependency information and are ordered using this information." Could someone please confirm what the right solution here is?

Comment: At my Ubuntu 11.10, comments about CONCURRENCY option at rc file tell that shell is an obsolte option, and by 2010-05-14 is an alias to makefile, the default.

Comment: A non GUI alternative to BUM (Boot Up manager)
Listing all services `service --status-all`
Removing a service `service --statusupdate-rc.d -f  service_name remove-all`

Comment: prelinking really doesn't help much. In fact, it is marginal benefit, see: http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/does-prelinking-speed-up-boot-times.html

Answer (score 43):

**Decrease your boot loader menu timeout**

Sounds trivial, but I found the default 10 seconds in Ubuntu is too long for my tastes. Say my screen takes a bit to auto-adjust the res, I see the counter reads 8 seconds at first sight.

I would edit the timeout to 3 seconds, giving me a second to see the boot menu (accounting for the time my screen adjusts to the res). Plenty of time, as pressing the arrow keys to select another item stops the counter.

**Grub** (before 9.10 Karmic)

```
sudo -i gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Find and edit the "**TIMEOUT**" line

**Grub 2** (new installs of 9.10 Karmic and after)

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find and edit the "**GRUB_TIMEOUT**" line, and run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 35):

If you are short of RAM, use [zramswap](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) or `zram-config` from Ubuntu repos. It's virtual swap that compresses unused RAM contents instead of putting them to disk (which usually freezes the system after you hit the RAM barrier). I experience little to no performance loss with it instead of system freezing every time I run out of RAM.

This works only for Natty and up (because you'll need kernel 2.6.37.1 or newer). For older systems you can use [compcache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56673/how-to-permanently-enable-compressed-ram-swap-what-version-to-use), but you'll have to set it up manually.

For those who never hit the RAM limit it gives some speed boost on HDD systems anyway, but you'd better [decrease swappiness](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F) to achieve the same effect.

SSD users: most likely you won't experience any speed boost, but zramswap can reduce SSD wear quite a lot.

Comment: Seems like a very useful app to have!

Comment: It's useful for low-ram systems, I wonder why it isn't installed by default for such systems?

Comment: @NoBugs because Ubuntu developers are very conservative. But it is enabled by default on Ubuntu Phone.

Comment: @Shnatsel "Google uses zram in Chrome OS and it is also available as an option for Android 4.4 devices" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram)

Answer (score 30):

I experienced an overall performance boost after I added the "[noatime](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html)" option to my filesystems (ext4 and reiserfs).

I cannot provide speed tests, but I invite you to try it and see for yourself.

Useful resource at Ubuntu Forum: [Saving hard drive with noatime in fstab](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=692318).

Comment: isn't relatime already the default in ubuntu?

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots: "I experienced an overall performance boost after I added the noatime option to my filesystems (ext4 and reiserfs)." -- Do you mean "relatime"? -- Nope, I meant "noatime" :D

Comment: This might break some email software that rely on this feature and a few backup tools. But for the casual user this should be OK as neither Thunderbird, nor Evolution would be affected. Though on Ubuntu, switching from relatime (default) to noatime won't bring much improvements. See http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/ how relatime works and you will understand that it will already dramatically decreased the number of last access time updates.

Comment: No source of public access doc or properly guided, no further steps.

Comment: Another source (from 2020), since the one linked in the answer is not public accessible anymore https://opensource.com/article/20/6/linux-noatime

Answer (score 30):

## Change your Mechanical Disk for a SSD

Solid State Drives are much faster and seems to be the most [bottleneck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck) in almost every computer nowadays.

I, for one, have experienced decrease in boot time from ~15 seconds to ~3 seconds, and great decrease in first start apps (Firefox, for example, from ~5 seconds to less than a second).

Want some benchmark? [Here](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9230882/Hard_disk_drives_vs._solid_state_drives_Are_SSDs_finally_worth_the_money_) is one.

Comment: If you computer's old, this may work mechanically (e.g. SSD with IDE connector), but as intended: a speed increase will depend on other bottlenecks of your system (like IDE connectors , for instance :)

Comment: I'm surprised this answer doesn't get more up-votes.

Comment: NVME network based is too faster the disk, even old laptop with SSD becomes lot more faster. Add 16+ GM RAM and no swap... great faster one

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure if my answer would qualify, because Ubuntu usually means GNOME and Ubuntu variations that use lighther alternatives have slightly different names, like Xubuntu.

Getting rid of GNOME is the first thing that I usually suggest. If you are happy with something lightweight like fluxbox, do it.

Comment: I know that Archlinux is not Ubuntu, but I saw an exaggerated  performance boost when I installed Ratpoison on my Archlinux box (yes, way too minimal for someone, but still a nitro boost for your box)

Comment: Agreed, try XMonad, it's awesome.

Comment: +1.  Or install Ubuntu, but switch to xfce after the install.

Comment: XFCE is a bit faster indeed, but just a bit and it uses the same amount of resources. Try Enlightenment (e.g. Bodhi Linux is Ubuntu 10.04 with Enlightenment), it's very lightweight and still has some visual effects of Compiz. Or try LXDE or Fluxbox, Linux Mint seems to have them integrated well.

Answer (score 21):

Set `vm.swappiness=10` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. I get a noticeable speed improvement when I fill memory. Since I use Eclipse most of the time, physical memory can become a sparse commodity.

EDIT:

From the [Ubuntu Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What%20is%20swappiness%20and%20how%20do%20I%20change%20it?):

"The default setting in Ubuntu is swappiness=60. Reducing the default value of swappiness will probably improve overall performance for a typical Ubuntu desktop installation. **A value of swappiness=10 is recommended**, but feel free to experiment. Note: Ubuntu server installations have different performance requirements to desktop systems, and the default value of 60 is likely more suitable."

The FAQ is pretty complete about explaining what swap is, how it is used and how to change it. Recommended reading for anyone thinking of tinkering with swappiness or the size of swap file on disk.

Comment: setting the value to 100 (max value I guess) will make the system swap from RAM to the disk a lot. doesn't that make it more slow, since it has to access the Hard Drive a lot more? I used to think that a lower value when you have a decent amount of RAM would be better.

Comment: @Erigami: +1 for mentioning something that *actually made a difference* to you.

Comment: @DecioLira: No. It pushes the apps I'm not currently using onto disk, meaning that the one I'm currently in has access to more physical memory.

Comment: Do you have any hardcore number that show the difference and in which situation and makes what kind of difference?

Comment: @txwikinger Nope. With lots of apps running it feels faster than a swappiness of 0 or 10.

Comment: @Erigami: I played around with swappiness for some time. And at the beginning it felt like it was faster, but with time it all seemed the same. Some real measurements would really be interesting.

Comment: Various tests I have done prove that vm.swappiness=100 is better than 10. On a slow machine it will help loads, on a fast one it will make no difference (unless you run multiple GB apps pages into ram). It is win-win.

Comment: wow, thank you. such an improvement in performance after doing this. I also appreciate that you showed Ubuntu's documentation that specified the recommended configuration for desktops.

Comment: for performance its good, but swap need for desktop when plan to use hibernate

Answer (score 19):

As silly as it sounds, always update your system!

Comment: Yes. I notice improvements immediately after doing so.

Comment: But: do so **manually** and perhaps via the command line. Daily updates via update mgr can freeze old systems (leaving you guessing what's going on).

Comment: No way just update, always require optimization and tuning the parameters

Answer (score 18):

Put your /tmp directory into a ram disk

https://superuser.com/questions/175861/ramdisk-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: If you do this, then *make sure* to check and/or clean your `/tmp` directory every so often, otherwise you run the risk of running out of RAM just because some app forgets to clean out its temporary files.  I read that this was actually a problem on some Solaris boxes at a point, because the OS would mount `/tmp` on a ramdisk and eventually it would fill up.  A good performance booster if you use it right, though.

Comment: Some have ram problem, this is for cpu!

Comment: generally this is only good advice if you have tons of ram, worth mentioning in the answer that this advice is not good option for PCs.

Comment: I did this. Then I faced shit problems. For example eclipse not opening, system not upgrading etc. Becouse tmp folder is full. tmp dir must be 6 gb at least.

Answer (score 16):

On one Ubuntu machine I have, I found that setting desktop effects to none (disabling all the graphical effects) made a huge UI speed improvement.

Comment: This setting can go both ways. Sometimes allowing the GPU to do the  work instead will free up the CPU and RAM and improve overall system performance.

Comment: Great -- how do you make that adjustment??

Comment: @ixtmixilix: Right click on the desktop and select the display option (it's the bottom one IIRC - I'm at work and have to use SomeOtherOS).

Comment: thanks... your comment may mean I don't switch back to Debian, which was light years faster due to being less flashy... for the record (if other people want to try it) you get there under the 'change desktop background' menu... (?)... sorry but calling it that reminds me a bit of SomeOtherOS

Comment: @ændrük How can I find out if which is the case for me? (whether my GPU is helping enough to keep desktop effects or whether I should disable them)

Comment: @Eyal I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to find out other than testing. The systems on which I've seen this change decrease performance were generally CPU-limited and had large display resolutions. If you'd like to learn more, I suggest opening a new question on the topic.

Answer (score 12):

## Tuning ext4 for maximum smoke

Enable writeback mode. This mode will typically provide the best ext4 performance. Note that it happens at cost of reliability as it disables journaling for writing data. Data may be written into the main filesystem after its metadata has been committed to the journal. As result old data may appear in files after a crash and journal recovery.

```
tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback /dev/sdXX

# Check fs options
dumpe2fs /dev/sdXX |more
```

[Documentation from kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt):

> In data=writeback mode, ext4 does not journal data at all.  This mode provides a similar level of journaling as that of XFS, JFS, and ReiserFS in its default mode - metadata journaling.  A crash+recovery can cause incorrect data to appear in files which were written shortly before the crash.  This mode will typically provide the best ext4 performance.

## Even more smoke

To squeeze even more performance add `fstab` options: `data=writeback,noatime,nodiratime`

i.e., edit your `/etc/fstab` find the UUID for your drives and add/replace existing options

```
/dev/sdXX /opt ext4 defaults,data=writeback,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
```

Ensure you have used tune2fs to turn on writeback mode BEFORE you edit your fstab file and BEFORE you reboot. I say BEFORE because I rebooted after I altered my fstab but before I turned on writeback mode and borked my boot. Nothing lost but I had to use a live CD to gain access and change my fstab. Safer if you enable on a non boot drive to test first.

Massive improvement in speed in both boot and shutdown and day to day use.

You can also turn off Journal mode that will give an added boost, for added safety make sure you have a UPS connected and working because with these features turned off your data isn't as safe, having said that my system doesn't have a UPS and it's power has been interrupted at least three times and I've suffered no data loss, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: may be its good to config these setting on laptop , no power down.....  good configs i will try it

Comment: `nodiratime` is not needed here because noatime implies it

Comment: One could throw in disabling device barriers if you're looking for data-eating tweaks. That can increase performance several times, but in case of power outage your files are screwed.

Comment: Oh the good old days of potentially corrupted file systems after a power cycle.

Answer (score 11):

Buy as much memory as you can afford and the machine can hold.

Comment: ørn, the idea behind this question is learn a little more about the system, and how to tune for people who are interested about it. Just buying a new machine/parts is an obvious answer that don't teach anything.

Comment: Then mention that in the question.  Buying more RAM is probably _the_ simplest and most efficient way to speed the system up at all (since Linux uses the unused memory as disk cache).

Comment: Also having more RAM than total program use and diskspace is pointless since past the size of all disks, there's nothing to stick in the write cache.

Comment: @hexafraction most typical machine configurations have much less RAM than disk space.  SSD-disks while fast, are still much slower than memory access.  An i7 has a max memory bandwith of 25,6 GB/s. http://ark.intel.com/products/75121/Intel-Core-i7-4765T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz

Comment: Buying more memory won't help you if you aren't getting near 100% memory usage unless you follow other steps (ramdisk).

Answer (score 8):

**The following is for experts only. As the name implies, it can and will eat your data, even if you are careful.**

[eatmydata](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/eatmydata) is a drop in package that will turn off fsync. Fsync is a system operation that ensures that your data is written to disk before continuing. Generally you want this, as it makes recovering from power outages and failures easier, faster, and less data lossy. It comes at a price though; anything calling fsycn will have to wait it's turn in line, rather than simply delivering data to the kernel to write at some later date. And in some, perhaps even many filesystems, fsync will write out all data, not just the stuff you're interested in protecting.

There are some specific situations where fsync isn't worth the cost. Imagine you have a server that number crunches a bunch of data. Rather than pointing this at a live database, it might be faster to dump into a consistent local database, install eatmydata to turn off fsync, and let that go. This can still crash and lose data, but since it's not the only copy of anything, you can just restart the process from scratch. Or, for example, Ubuntu's build servers, where all we care about is the final package produced. Or, on the desktop side, if a program (like Firefox) is syncing so much it's slowing the entire system down. Just be prepared to lose all data associated with using this, or face dire consequences.

Answer (score 6):

Close applications that are not used all the time.

A lot of standard applications use a lot of memory and often also CPU while they are running in the background. Webbrowser, email clients etc are very inefficient in memory usage and the javascripts embedded often use CPU time with no benefit to the user.

Just by only running the applications that are used currently, the system will be a lot faster. Also, stopping applications is the only way of freeing memory lost in memory leaks.

The startup of the application on a fast running system is often less than switching windows on an overloaded and slow system.

Comment: Yea but that kind of goes without saying.

Comment: My CPU's fan was turning on a lot when I left Firefox open. I stopped using FF and switched to Chrome. I know that isn't a direct performance improvement, but I presume the CPU is being hogged less so other apps could use it more.

Comment: @Dmitriy Likhten: How many people have an e-mail client run in the background? We should give them a lightweight applet instead that notifies of new e-mail, and the e-mail client is only opened when the e-mails are read.

Comment: For an e-mail client, I suspect it would be counterproductive. When it's only waiting for new mail, most of its memory can be swapped. And loading back from swap might be faster than loading all the separate file that the mail client is using. OTOH, this tip is highly relevant for a web browser, where as you mention even background tabs/windows are often using a little CPU time and can't be swapped because of some animated pictures or javascript on a timer.

Comment: Well.. the problem is that swapping is unfortunately often slower than using no swap but enough memory available to start the application in its entirety. While swapping seems to work well on servers, on desktops its seems to do more damage than helping in my experience (I also have to say that this is one of the deterioration of the Linux kernel in the last 5 or so years. Swapping used to work lots better).

Answer (score 6):

Unity tends to be a bit resource-hungry, though I am surprised to hear that you experienced similarly poor performance even under Unity2D. One possible solution would be to play around with other more lightweight Desktop Environments such as Lubuntu (LXDE) or Xubuntu (XFCE). I think you will see a substantial difference in overall responsiveness and performance.

Additionally, you can try going into the Startup Applications manager and unchecking applications and processes that you don't need Ubuntu to automatically start for you at login (e.g. Bluetooth Manager if you don't have bluetooth, UbuntuOne if you don't use it, programs you simply don't use, etc.) Before doing this, first make hidden startup applications visible in startup manager:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Comment: Come on, Unity is more than capable of running perfectly on a machine with 4Gb of RAM and a dual-core processor. Suggesting to try LXDE would make sense on a netbook with 1Gb of RAM and an Atom processor. Surely the OP's problem is caused by some misconfiguration or hardware incompatibility, not by the fact that Unity can't run on that hardware.

Comment: You may be completely right about the cause of Christian's problems, and you are certainly right in thinking that Unity should (theoretically) be running perfectly smoothly on his machine. However, neither of these facts in any way negate my statement that Unity is resource-hungry (regardless of machine specs) and that using LXDE or XFCE would undoubtedly yield significant performance improvements. It may not be the ideal solution in this situation (hence my designation of the suggestion as "one possible solution"), but my hope was that it might at least improve his experience.

Comment: @Sergey Please don't forget that there are many of us still using non-upgradeable netbooks limited to 1G just because they've failed to fail us yet. Selecting your toolset with regards to its memory-footprint does not make you or your computer a dinosaur (even of one of you is ;).

Comment: @Sergey For me Lubuntu (default install) is significantly faster on my laptop than Ubuntu (default install). It is 4GB RAM, dual-core laptop with very poor graphic card. In my case Unity effects cause very significant slowdown. Maybe it is was also caused in part by stupid defaults or hardware incompatibility - but worse defaults and worse hardware support are for me also valid reasons to avoid Unity.

Answer (score 6):

1. Use **JFS** filesystem.  It's *rock solid*.  It has *lowest CPU usage* and a very good overall performance.
2. Set vm.vfs_cache_pressure.  This is my /etc/sysctl.d/10-desktop-responsiveness

   [prefix the comment lines with a #, this web interface does not like them...]

   These settings increase responsiveness for a typical desktop workload.

vm.swappiness instructs the linux kernel to favour application code over
caches when these two compete for RAM.

vm.vfs_cache_pressure controls inode/dentry (i.e. filesystem) cache vs.
 other caches, i.e. we want to keep filesystem meta-data in RAM if possible.

From: http://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that

```
vm.swappiness=15

vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

Comment: "JFS filesystem. It's rock solid. It has lowest CPU usage and a very good overall performance" - what about providing some confirmation, beyond "somebody told me this"? Any kind of benchmark? In what situations it is good - for example, would it be also a good idea on a modern computer with SSD?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a look at what services are started after booting on Ubuntu 10.04 run "jobs-admin".

```
sudo apt-get install jobs-admin
```

Answer (score 5):

**Configure Swap**

Part 1. Set swappiness. This *may* be as per degusa's answer, but it could be the opposite, and it'll have more effect when it is.

One scenario that some of us are happy to be in is when we have plenty of RAM. Generally, we've a small percentage of it being directly used by the kernel and applications, some (maybe a large amount if you've used other tweaks to boost performance such as mounting /tmp in memory) used for ramfs and tmpfs, and gigs and gigs being used as a disk cache to make our file-access faster.

In this scenario once the total used memory including cache becomes high, and an application needs more RAM, linux has to decide whether to take some cache from the file system, or swap out to the swap partition/file.

Since we've tonnes of RAM, and quite possibly only bothered with swap at all so we could enable hibernation, we want it to lean toward taking some of that copious cache, and hence want a low swappiness. If we don't care about being able to hibernate, we might even find that such a high-RAM machine doesn't need swap at all.

Another scenario is someone with low RAM who is switching between a few heavy applications and spending a reasonable amount of time on each. Imagine perhaps a web dev who spends some time on their IDE, some on a graphics editor, some on their browser of choice, a bit on some other browsers to check on compatibility issues, and maybe 5 minutes every hour on their mail client. They're also likely hitting the same files repeatedly with reads and writes and hence benefiting appreciably from file caching. This person could probably benefit from linux being more eager to swap out the memory used by whichever of those heavy applications they're currently not active on, so swappiness should probably be higher for them.

Not only is the best setting for them likely to be higher than the most common advice, but they're probably going to notice it more than the person who always has gigs to spare anyway, too.

Part 2. Priority & number of partitions.

Each swap partition has a priority, and linux will use that with the highest first. If not set in /etc/fstab, it'll be treated as negative starting with -1 (explicit settings are between 0 and 32767 and so -1 is lower than any explicitly set) and continuing in order in fstab to -2, -3 and so on.

The best setting depends upon where the partitions physically are. If you've only one, then it doesn't matter (but maybe you should have more than one, so read on).

If you've two or more on the same physical drive, then they should have different priorities so that it doesn't try to use two partitions that require seeking between them (does anyone know if this is automatically avoided?). The defaults are fine. It's probably not a good idea to have two swaps on the same drive anyway, but it can happen if you created one and then decided you needed more swap later (perhaps when adding more RAM).

If you've two or more on two or more physical drives that are of about equal speed, then setting them to the same priority will mean linux will use them both at the same time, which offers better performance for reasons analogous to why RAID or simply ensuring that there are frequently used files on both drives will - the work gets split between them.

If you've two or more physical drives of equal speed but have swap only on one, maybe you should change that, for the above reasons.

If you've two or more physical drives, of very different speeds, then generally you want the fastest drive to have a higher priority than the slower, so it's used first. You may not even want to have any swap on the slower, though it might make sense if you e.g. have a small swap on a fast but small drive for fast swap, and a larger swap on the slower drive so you've enough space to hibernate.

If the faster of the two is an SSD, then there's two alternatives with different pros and cons:

1. Highest-priority, or perhaps only, swap on the SSD, for speed.
2. Only swap on the non-SSD, to reduce writes on the SSD and hence increase its lifetime.

Number 2 is probably the one to go for if you only really have swap to allow for hibernation and otherwise your copious RAM means you don't really need it (and if you're spending money on an SSD, you should spend it on RAM too) unless perhaps you're a boot-up speed fanatic who wants to boot from hibernation at a speed that'll show off your fancy high-spec rig! Otherwise, the balance is all about speed vs SSD lifetime.

If you've a drive existing solely for swap so as not to compete with other file I/O, then you presumably are hard-core about performance and already know about this stuff better than me and are only reading this to see if I got anything wrong!

Answer (score 4):

If we are talking about getting from BIOS to internet connectivity i can recommend setting up network without using NetworkManager, personally I've done this because i have a very sluggish DHCP server and NetworkManager doesn't start probing for network until i've logged in.

Comment: Boot time is an important performance aspect. how one goes about setting up network without NetworkManager?

Comment: Disable "Connect automaticly" in Networkmanager and take a look at this http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/how-do-i-configure-wifi-to-log-in-to-wpa-at-boot-time-regardless-of-user-being-l you can also look at `man interfaces`

Comment: I removed NetworkManager and its Gnome friend once and for all...

Comment: Me to, doesnt really need in anyways, you can do all the same things from the terminal any way..

Comment: There is an alternative to NetworkManager called Wicd I used to use to get rid of the password on boot and so that it would start the network before the desktop: http://wicd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

If you use a Unity desktop then try a more lightweight interface like LXDE or Xfce.

Answer (score 4):

The ubuntu-tweak utility has a handy "Janitor" tool that allows you to clear caches and orphan packages very easily.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Note that as of 2016-04-16 Ubuntu Tweak is abandoned, with last update over year ago - see https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak (what makes http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2012/10/22/thank-you-ubuntu-tweak-will-continue.html outdated).

[image: Ubuntu Tweak's Janitor]

Comment: Bleachbit is also great - and works crossplatform, cleaning some things ubuntu-tweak doesn't (and vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

Use `apt-fast` instead of `apt-get`, and put your apt cache on tmpfs.

You'll need aria or axel for apt-get to work so first either:

```
apt-get install aria2c
```

or

```
apt-get install axel
```

I've used aria.
Then you need apt-fast itself.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

Answer the questions, and from then on apt-fast will act like apt-get in just about every regard except that it downloads packages in parallel. It makes no difference if you are going to install a single application, but lots for larger installs.

In combination, with this, my /etc/fstab has:

```
tmpfs /var/cache/apt/archives tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

This has the downside that if the same package is used several times over different boots, it'll have to download it again, but then it may have been updated in the meantime anyway. It has the upsides of faster access of them, automatic clean-up of unused packages on reboot.

Since I've been re-installing a lot over the course of these experiments, it allowed me to do a comparison. After installation of 12.04 one will at the time of writing have about 300 updates including a kernel update available just after installing. I ignored software updater and did the above changes before `apt-fast update && apt-fast dist-upgrade` and the download part is many times faster (the actual installation takes the same time).

I have an alias of `alias apt-get="apt-fast"` so I don't even need to change habits (the only differences are different feedback on the download, a confirmation on whether I want to download them, and an implied `sudo`  should I forget it, but the commands to trigger anything is the same).

Answer (score 4):

Found what was slowing down my machine: `gwibber-service`. Maybe because I have an account in twitter that follows a lot of people and when it refreshed the machine went bad.

I was monitoring the machine with top as said @kmassada and when it was really slow noticed the process. Then executing:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

as @blasmat indicated to go through Startup Applications I could see that the service started automatically and I disabled it. Now my computer is much faster. I think there are still improvements I can make (I don't feel it at it top conditions), but after 20 hours of testing the performance I can say it really goes well.

Answer (score 3):

Another good way to boost performance is to install CompizConfig Settings Manager, and disable animation effects, Fading Windows, and Window Decorations. Desktop wall and Expo are an option, too.

[image]

Also, use fast texture filter under OpenGL

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Try a light-weight community flavour of Ubuntu

Instead of messing with your Ubuntu system: make a fresh installation of a *community flavour of Ubuntu*, a flavour with the same Ubuntu engine under the hood, but with a lightweight desktop environment, and with lighter application programs.

- the ultra-light **Lubuntu** or
- the medium light **Ubuntu MATE** or **Xubuntu**.

Try them live before installing. It is a good idea to keep using LTS releases, and I suggest that you start with 16.04.1 LTS, which is the version with the longest remaining support until End Of Life. See detailed tips at the following links,

- [Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)
- [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)
- [Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)

#### The version with longest support time (when this is written)

It is somewhat tricky to find **16.04.1 LTS**, the version with the longest support time. The following links work (2017-06-29),

- Ubuntu: [old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/)
- Lubuntu 16.04, **16.04.1** and 16.04.2: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release)
- Ubuntu MATE 16.04, **16.04.1** and 16.04.2: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04.2/release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04.2/release/)
- Xubuntu 16.04, **16.04.1** and 16.04.2: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/16.04.2/release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/16.04.2/release)

Answer (score 2):

**RAID for everything!**

(I'm experimenting with a lot of tips out there on performance, as the task is teaching me a lot of stuff, and as per the request in the original question, I'll make a separate post for each).

If you've more than one drive, you can set up RAID. The pros and cons of different RAID levels is well documented all over the place, so I won't go into it. Personally I have two drives so I'm really picking between 0 and 1 (though mdadm can do a form of 5 on just two drives, but I haven't tried it). Since there are things that can go wrong with a computer - especially a laptop that has a greater risk of physical mishap - that no RAID level can save you from, and you therefore need a strategy for dealing with risks that doesn't depend on RAID to save your bacon, (it won't save you if you experiment with a performance tweak you read on the internet and it makes things unbootable, for example) I decided to go with RAID 0.

The easiest way to do this for the whole system is to install from the alternate ISO rather than the desktop installer that lets you boot straight off the CD/DVD/USB into Ubuntu.

Select "Manual" paritioning. Divide up your disks so that you've partitions you will use on each disk. E.g. if you've two disks and decided to set aside 100GB for /home then you would set aside 50GB on each if using RAID 0, 100GB on each if using RAID 1.

Select "Configure Software Raid". Select "Create RAID Volume" (or something close to that, I'm not going to boot into the installer to check the wording). Pick those partitions you want in your first RAID volume, the type of RAID, and create it. Repeat until you have all of your volumes set up. (You don't need to put your swap on RAID, just give the two or more swap partitions the same priority in fstab and they'll be used together without RAID).

The assign filesystems and what's mounted where as you would with any installation and away you go.

A lot of stuff out there says you can only have /boot on a RAID 1 or non-RAID partition. I've had it on RAID 0 without any problems, which may be a matter of Ubuntu moves on, linux moves on, or BIOS moves on (and if its the last then your BIOS may not be okay with /boot on RAID 0).

The installer will install grub on all your drives. This gives one the benefit that if something stops booting on your "first" drive stops working, you can go into the boot menu and boot off the second.

hdparm does indeed see things has having been doubled in speed for me, and there's certainly a perceptible increase in speed on a lot of things too. I found in experimenting that the first part of booting (after the grub menu, when you've blank purple) seems to be slower, the second part to be faster (rarely time to show the animation now) and application use is faster - the greatest increase in performance of any of the tips I've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would check for what processes are running and which ones are using up the most memory. There might be something you are installing that is a memory hogger. use top command or system monitor.

If you are not into eye candy, I even recommend installing the following packages. I noticed a considerable response time between unity and basic gnome

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-session-fallback
```

I would also check my startup applications to see what runs at start up and what I don't need to run at start up.

And I would also check responsiveness in specific applications.

last thing I would check graphics settings. Maybe you need to compromise battery life for performance.

Answer (score 1):

***Each of the kernel parameters are in a field = value format.

For example, the parameter `kernel.threads-max = 16379` sets the maximum number of concurrent processes to 16,379.

This is smaller than the maximum number of unique PIDs (65,536). Lowering the number of PIDs can improve performance on systems with slow CPUs or little RAM since it reduces the number of simultaneous tasks. On high-performance computers with dual processors, this value can be large. As an example, my 350 MHz iMac is set to 2,048, my dual-processor 200 MHz PC is set to 1024, and my 2.8 GHz dual processor PC is set to 16,379.

**Tip**: The kernel configures the default number of threads based on the available resources. Installing the same Ubuntu version on different hardware may set a different value. If you need an identical system (for testing, critical deployment, or sensitive compatibility), be sure to explicitly set this value.

There are two ways to adjust the kernel parameters.

First, you can do it on the command line. For example, `sudo sysctl -w kernel.threads-max=16000`. This change takes effect immediately but is not permanent; if you reboot, this change will be lost.

The other way to make a kernel change is to add the parameter to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. Adding the line `kernel.threads-max=16000` will make the change take effect on the next reboot.

Usually when tuning, you first use `sysctl –w`. If you like the change, then you can add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Using `sysctl –w` first allows you to test modifications. In the event that everything breaks, you can always reboot to recover before committing the changes to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

***I learned that from this [extreme tech](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,1697,2114123,00.asp) article.

Comment: How is lowering the total number of threads supposed to make a difference to performance? It's rarely reached on most systems anyway. It could be useful on a server whose main job is to serve http requests, but what evidence do you have that the default setting is not the best?

Comment: @gilles I mentioned a tip, I thought might be useful. Regardless if a computer reaches max number of threads, if it is slow it would be beneficial to lower the maximum number of threads. Also no one ever stated that this couldn't be a computer serving http requests.

Comment: There are plenty of people who've found some setting and decided to tweak it, and then posted it to the web with some dodgy explanation of why it would improve performance, without ever checking whether it did make a difference. Sometimes someone bothers to check, and often they discover that the default setting is there for a reason, namely that the original author *did* test and chose a reasonable default. So my question still stands: can you cite a benchmark that shows that (at least in some circumstances) the default setting is not appropriate?

Comment: @gilles default setting are default for a reason appealing to the most people, those who wish not to tweak can go on with their lives. Although If your among the sticklers (and i am sure you are) then your more than welcome to benchmark it. let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you edit video files, set up a stripped RAID 0 configuration for your video files. I noticed significant improvement in the smoothness of video editing after I did this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0

Of course you will need a minimum to two hard drives to do this, and it's easier if they are separate from the drive the OS is on (If you only have two hard drives, as I did, you can create a mirrored, RAID 1, boot partition and then a RAID 0 partition for everything else).

Note that since RAID 0 provides no fault tolerance or redundancy, the failure of one drive will cause the entire array to fail; as a result of having data striped across all disks, the failure will result in total data loss.

Answer (score 1):

I find strange that no one has mentioned anything about Unity. Unity is definitely something that one should consider removing if the system has to work faster (I shall not discuss whether Unity boost the user's productivity or not since this is quite subjective for many people).

I just got my hands on a virtual appliance created with VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity in it. The default machine settings were 32MB memory for video, 2GB for RAM and 100% performance cap on the CPU (single one was chosen). Of course my CPU is a bad one (a 5-6 years old i3 from Intel with 1.66GHz and two cores). Because of the huge amount of RAM that was dedicated to the VM and the presence of only 3.8GB physical memory on my host I decided to reduce it to 512MB. It was unbelievable how sluggish the system was.

The [recommended minimum system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) given by Canonical are a joke. I cannot imagine anyone working at all under such conditions. Yes, these are **minimum** requirements but what is usually understood by that is that the system is still usable to a some non-suicidal degree with the exception of working with applications that require a lot more. The window manager should not put such a huge restriction on the hardware used (Windows Vista anyone?) especially since Canonical removed the Gnome 2 Classic option upon login (currently there are of course alternative, which are however not officially supported by Canonical). Appearance is something important especially if we follow one of the most profound rules in design and usability - "Form follows function". It should not however do what Unity does to the system resources. I strongly recommend starting from reducing the fancy-pancy garbage on your system and the first thing towards that is to replace Unity with for example LXDE, which looks great, offers a lot of room for customization (Unity and customization - pfffff...) and is a beast when it comes to small CPU usage and miniature memory footprint combined with the functionality it provides. My VM is currently flying after a single step of installing vanilla lxde:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lxde
```

A much more better way is to go for one of the variations of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu (LXDE) or Xubuntu (XFCE), which profit from the fact they share the same repositories, security updates, patches etc. with Ubuntu yet do not suck the life out of your machine. Installing another window manager on top of Ubuntu (which defaults to Unity) definitely helps a lot but Ubuntu's default installation also comes with a huge amount of resource-hungry services and applications most (all?) of which have more lightweight alternatives.

Comment: I find that Unity is actually very fast on some computers and very slow on others. I think this might just be a video card driver issue or something. I use Xubuntu, myself, though, as I find more utility in it, and Unity is slow on my current computer (which far exceeds Unity's requirements).

Answer (score 0):

**Using `localhost` as the the host name**

This method could improve the speed of start the application .

`nano /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1          localhost Ubuntu
127.0.1.1          Ubuntu
```

In the **end** of the **first line**, add the **host name**, which is the name of the **second line**.

Comment: I'm curious about what that tweak is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question and I didn't ask because I don't believe it. I wanted technical details. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: gui load faster ..tested in redhat 5

Comment: This provides no information as to why we should follow your advice. Some context and benchmarks please.

Answer (score 0):

**ADVANCED, DO NOT DO IF YOU DO NOT KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING**

Compile your own kernel. http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-configure-and-compile-a-custom-linux-kernel-for-ubuntu It may take quite some time, so do something else while you compile it. Once you're done, install the files and celebrate. Especially if you get huge speed improvements. :D

Comment: Does anyone know if there are any remotely recent benchmarks that substantiate the idea that using a self-configured, self-built kernel is likely to produce significant speed improvements in current Ubuntu desktop systems? (If so, perhaps that information could be added to this answer.)

Comment: Even if compiling your own kernel does not dramatically improve speed, it is a good Linux exercise that you should certainly do if you want to get more experienced with Linux (or, alternatively, if you are just super curious and want to find out what is happening under the hood).

Comment: For the time spent configuring your own kernel, the 0.2 seconds shaved off boot time and the <0.1% performance improvement under load is definitely worth the hassle </sarcasm>       * numbers from my own experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXT4 file system

Adding noatime and nodiratime
Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add discard to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Disable hibernation
Edit

```
# nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

Look for

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Change from “yes” to “no”, there are two, one for hibernation, and another one for suspend. If you have to disable them both, make sure to replace them both from yes to no.

```
<allow_active>no</allow_active>
```

Tmpfs

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the line to the end of fstab file

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

If logs aren’t important for you (laptop or desktop), you can also mount /var/log to

```
tmpfs. Add the line to the end of fstab file
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=0755 0 0
```

Preload
To install preload on Ubuntu, Linux Mint or debian based distributions

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install preload
```

To install preload on Fedora, Centos or Redhat based distributions

```
# yum install preload
```

Swap and Swapiness
To change swappiness setting:

```
$ su -
# nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And add this line into sysctl.conf file.

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

You can read more at nam huy linux blog How to tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu, Linux Mint http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. A few remarks. You don't explain how to use EXT4 or how to check if you are already using it. The fstab thing only applies if you are running a SSD. Please explain this **before** telling what to change. How will disabling hibernation improve performance? `yum` should be `apt-get` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers say a lot, already. However, make sure you're using the optimal video card driver for your system. Using the wrong one can really slow it down. The best one for my system on Xubuntu 15.04 is the legacy Nvidia one. The newest version and the open source one are either slower with certain applications (such as Tkinter apps and SciTE), or they crash my computer.

I might recommend not using lightdm for locking your screen and such, because unless they've fixed it in this new release, it's a lot slower going to sleep and waking up than what they used to use. That might seem program-specific, but it really does go a long way toward a faster computer, practically speaking, in my opinion.

I would recommend looking at hardware instead of software tweaks, after you've done all the software tweaks you can handle. You might consider a solid state hard drive.

You also might consider using a different window manager.

Answer (score 0):

One desktop that I would definitely recommend over Unity, or even XFCE, is **i3**. There's a website for it [here](https://i3wm.org/). I have seen major improvements in performance, even on my netbook with 1GB of RAM.