# Does Preload in conlict with other read-ahead type processes?

Tags: boot

I would assume not as Preload is installed to use idle priority. Though I wonder if it is a duplication of efforts with other processes installed in Ubuntu. Does anyone have any more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have been using preload for some years on all my ubuntu installations and never had any problems. And I'm quite prone to [tinkering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/) with the system.

Even the launchpad preload [bug's page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/preload/+bugs?field.status:list=NEW) does not list any direct conflicts.

I would say you are safe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems like it works quite well. I see no regressions so I will mark this answered.

Answer (score 2):

I ran it on Ubuntu 10.10 on a system that really needed performance as I was developing on it.  I was using LXDE as the desktop environment and I didn't notice any problems with it.  It had only 1Gb ram and 1.8Ghz processor.  I did notice things I used more frequently like chromium or mysql query browser did seem to start faster after a few days of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the current status is. But back in 9.10 I had problems with really long boot and login times it turns out the preload just wasn't working at all and it wasn't just me, I found other threads where the preload package was just broken. It might be fixed now though.

Comment: As I said before the preload daemon runs with Idle I/O priority now. That likely fixed the issue.