# What to do to improve the speed of a laptop with Ubuntu?

Tags: performance, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I'm looking for some tricks to improve the performance of my laptop.

I'm using Compiz, which makes my Ubuntu really nice looking and got some awesome features … But … the startup of many programs is a little bit slow, opening my external harddisk takes 5 to 10 seconds …

Answer (score 2):

You can make some improvements by moving `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` to your RAM.

First, edit `/etc/fstab` and add following lines:

```
tmpfs /tmp     tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

Next, remove all files from `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` and mount new RAM partitions:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sysklogd stop
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/*
sudo mount -a
sudo /etc/init.d/sysklogd start
```

Also, you can move Firefox cache to RAM. Type `about:config` in Firefox address bar and hit Enter. Right click in the parameter listing and select New->String. Set the preference name to `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory` and set the value to `/tmp`.
Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance) - these things are not going to be very different on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try xubuntu or lubuntu for some more speed. Also try turning compiz up. Sorry but that really has to do with the preformance