# How to keep Ubuntu in max performance?

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I try to use the CPU Frequency Monitor in Performance but every time I logout, restar, turn off the machine the configuration change to on demand.

How i can keep 'Performance' permanently

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. This is a specific question about CPU frequency settings (it can be on Adaptive, or Minimal, or Performance, etc), and the OP wishes to run in Performance mode - faster computer, more power usage. It's apparently reverting to "On Demand" every restart. Legit question, though it could do with some more details.