# Ubuntu 11.10 is slow

Tags: 11.10, performance

It's much slower than 11.04. My laptop is new and quite powerful, so it's not the issue. 
Everything just loads slower (music, browser, files, everything!). Why is that? What should I do?

Comment: Can you add more detail to you question?

Comment: OR if you are in really need of speed you could try Lubuntu it's faster.

Comment: Related: [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upgrade your 11.04 installation to 11.10? If so, try installing a fresh copy of 11.10. After upgrading, everything was slow to me. I did a fresh install and everything seems fine now.

Comment: Doing a fresh install can also help clean out your system, which helps improve performance. One particular area is extra packages you may not need anymore without realizing it. If I do a fresh install and I forget to eventually reinstall something, then I consider that unnecessary junk I've taken off my system.