# Very Slow Boot Up time and low battery life

Tags: boot, time, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I have a i3 laptop with Ubuntu 11.10(64bit) and the boot last 30-40 seconds.... how can I make it faster? Also my laptop is just 5-6 mounths and my battery last only 2h 2h 20min with jupiter and the brightness at the minimum level can anyone help?

Comment: Kind of related http://askubuntu.com/q/2194/. Some answers may help, as disabling unused programs at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try out lubuntu, faster boot up time and less  CPU intensive, lengthening battery life and shortening boot time. See lubuntu.org for more information.

Comment: but I really like Unity.... and I think lubuntu is a bit essential but witout any eye-candy.... The battery problem is a kernel problems so I need a program to do that.... Also the boot time is very very slow(35 seconds) it's not possible....

Answer (score 0):

Install "powertop" (which you may find in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

It is a command-line utility, which you may find difficult to use, but if you find some tutorials, you could tweak things in your hardware to expend less battery charge.

In my case, I improved from 1:30 hours of charge at common use (surfing the web, mid-brightness), up to 2:20 hours of charge.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the battery life, try the recommendations in the following Wiki

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks