# New system runs WAY slow.. What to look for?

Tags: performance, cpu-load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I have a new Ubuntu installation (11.10) on an older machine (Intel P4 1.7G).  System monitor shows CPU usage pegged most of the time, and in the 40-50% range when the machine is idle.  Processes all seem to be Sleeping most of the time, except gnome-system-monitor which is in the 10-20% range most of the time.  This machine did pretty well running XP.  Are there any tools I can use to find the culprit(s)?

Comment: top is a classic to identify what process is using so much CPU. Often the problem will be with either video drivers and / or wireless. Can you identify your hardware.

Comment: It looks like system monitor is quite a hog all by itself.  System load indicator is much less obtrusive.  I've also switched to Unity 2D while I try to sort out some video questions (ATI rage video card and a funky 1400 x 900 display).  Thanks for the help