# How to speed up Ubuntu 11.10 (Desktop)

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed in rather old desktop pc.I'd like to continue using it with more speed but installing new hardware maybe impossible.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a lightweight DE

Use xfce OR Lxde even just bare WM like openbox, fluxbox etc

- Use lighter applications

  2. Midori to Firefox, Chromium
  3. Abiword, gnumeric to libreoffice
- Remove unnecessary services and scripts.

  E.g. If you have a desktop without bluetooth, wireless you can remove bluetooth daemon and services package and even network-manager if you use ethernet only

Some system enhancement advice here as well.
[How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)