# speeding up computer

Tags: 10.04, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

After running update manager on my computer and finished its job, my computer runs slower than past. Moreover, opening time of my computer, pushing power on button, takes more time.

Cpu usage of XORG is high if I compare it with past.

How can I speed up my computer ?

NOTE: ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

12.04 has a few performance updates i think, because lots of apps opens quickly  if compared to 10.04 you can upgrade to it if you want.

Comment: Before updating my computer, my computer opens lots of the program quickly. But, I think if I upgrade to 12.04 and making regular update, The result will be same.

Comment: i really think that's the only way to do it. 
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/press-reaction-to-ubuntu-12-04-mostly-positive/
as u see they say that it's so much faster then before, and i am using it,it's really better.