# Ubuntu is really slow

Tags: performance

I installed Ubuntu through out Windows. I know it should go a little slow, but it is quite a slow and my chipset makes noise as it where working really hard. Windows 7 works fine.

My computer is an Acer 5742G, I3, Nvida 540m, 4 GB RAM. I think there must be a missing driver, but I don't know how to install them as I am a new user.

Can some one give me a link to a good video tutorial?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a lighter distribution, like LUBUNTU http://lubuntu.net. However, after looking over your specs. It may be a driver or kernel issue that has already been fixed. Run an update after you finish and reboot and see what happens.

I'm assuming you replaced windows correct? or are you virtualizing ubuntu through windows. If you are virtualizing ubuntu through windows your computer has to run windows AND UBUNTU at the same time. I would recommend allowing ubuntu to RESIZE a partition on your hard drive and install itself there.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Frank, consider purchasing an extra hard drive and installing Ubuntu on that. If that is not viable, resize partitions in Windows (type "disk management" in start and choose the first thing). Format the partition, then reboot with the Ubuntu CD/USB plugged in. Enter a live session, and install from there.