# Unity and Firefox are running slow

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. All the applications are running quite slow, so is Unity and the web browser. For example HD quality Youtube videos are lagging and scrolling down pages lags.

My specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- 8 GB ddr2 800 MHz RAM
- Intel core 2 duo 2.0GHz
- 750 GB HDD

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu, also Do you have any Graphic Card on your system. Adding your Laptop Model number will be helpful too.

Comment: Try to login with Unity 2d.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score -4):

Use Gnome panel, better than unity.

As Firefox consumes much of CPU, many people are complaining of its speed, be it Windows or Linux.

Use Google Chrome browser instead of Firefox. It is very faster.

Comment: I think the user wants to use OOTB, which includes FFox and Unity or gnome-shell