# I have slow performance on my Ubuntu installation, what can I try?

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Everything I do on Ubuntu takes ages, what can I do to speed things up?

Comment: Post hardware specs/model of machine and what version you're on!!

Comment: @mateo_salta Looked for it before but couldn't find it so I made a new one. let's close this one then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

**Software**

- **install preload**. `sudo apt-get install preload` it will run in the
  background and may improve performance. Programs may start quicker.
- **Update your system.** `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or open the update manger.
- **Unity-2D** instead of the default Unity. log out, at the log-in screen click on the *gear* symbol, choose Unity-2d instead of Unity.
- **[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)**, or just `lubuntu-desktop`
- **[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)**, or just `xubuntu-desktop`

**Hardware**

- **Upgrade your RAM**, Ubuntu uses a lot of RAM.

**Drivers**

- What drivers are you using for your video card, etc. is it an open
  source variant or is it nvidas own? (or Radeon, intel, etc. )

Comment: It also depends on your hardware. I have seen both video drivers and wireless drivers cause significant slow downs.

Comment: How about preload? and disabling startup applications.