# How can I make my PC faster?

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

My computer is running very slow. It appears I may be running Ubuntu 10.04. Please let me know how to increase it's performance.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Can you post the output of the command: `sudo lshw -short` - Also, do you use ubuntu 10.04? Have you tried 12.04, the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 12.04 could help.

Often it helps to make some hardware changes, such as upgrading your RAM or getting a faster hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to speed up your system by freeing up your RAM. For this go to a terminal and type:

```
free -m
```

You will get your RAM information along with your swap memory info. By freeing up the RAM you can speed up your Ubuntu system. To free up your RAM, type:

```
sudo -s
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Then finally

```
free -m
```

You can see the difference from this output. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, speeding your system involves couple of step, if upgrading your hardware is not in the cards, do following steps:

Speed is mostly determined by available RAM,so choose a light DE such as XFCE or LXDE or Even Awesome or Wmii window manager.

You can check the unnecessary services and processes running that you don't need.Say you have apache and MySQL running in your LAMP server and you don't need them at that time you can close it.

Next use and updated kernel, latest kernels do perform better and if you are using AMD graphics drivers, Open Source Drivers do perform better.

Plus having some swap space allocated is always good.

Comment: "AMD graphics drivers, Open Source Drivers do perform better." Uh.. no.. have you ever played a 3D game with those drivers.. bad idea.

Comment: Bad Idea, haha.

Comment: Last time i checked i could play any medium graphics game  i wanted easily, There is lot of stuff apart from gaming on a Ubuntu Box, and seriously do u use Ubuntu for serious gaming. Sounds hilarious.

Comment: No i don't because most demanding games won't even run and, because of that I don't use the open source drivers besides they don't offer overscaning which is just.. wow.