# AMD E1-1200 Slow?

Tags: 12.04, flash, amd-processor, toshiba

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 32bit with Gnome 3 on a Toshiba 850D-104 for a friend of mine. This friend only surfs the web, checks for emails and plays online flash games a lot

I was chocked to see that the laptop was rather sluggish. I mean you get what you pay for, with this kind of processor (AMD E1-1200, dual-core 1.4Ghz), but it's a bit too much!
It takes 10 seconds to just open up Chromium (1 tab!) not to mention when he plays a flash-game it's stuttery and becomes unplayable.

What can I do? I already tried Lubuntu, but it's not that much faster. I checked the resources and the ram is only 300Mb from the 6Gig installed? The Graphics card is a AMD HD Radeon 7310 (and the FGLRX-driver is installed)

Any solutions for a sluggish Flash experience on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: What is the CPU usage like? Try running "top" in a terminal to see if anything is eating away at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same laptop - the Toshiba Satellite 850D-M1050 with the AMD E1-1200 processor. I did not have slightest bit of a problem running ubuntu 12.04 on 4Gb memory.

The issues could be - Place your sata device in performance mode and the processor is set by default to always slow- set it to dynamic in the BIOS

Install the latest fglrx graphics driver (maybe you are still using the standard gallium one)

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

Reduce swappiness on your system.. there is an article about it too:

- [How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)