# Ubuntu fails to load after installing fglrx

Tags: ati, graphics, xorg, xubuntu

I am using a Toshiba Satellite notebook with Xubuntu 12.10 x86_64. Just now, I installed the `fglrx` package to be able to use the propriety drivers for my graphics card. However, once I rebooted after installing the package, Xubuntu fails to load.

The loading screen (Xubuntu logo; left-right moving bar) appears for a few seconds before the screen turns black and a log of a bunch of daemons starting appears. I press ALT + F4 to log in to a terminal, but when I try starting Xubuntu by running `startx`, I get this error at the end:

```
...
Loading extension GLX
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:1:1) found
SetVBEMode failed

Fatal server error:
no screens found
(EE)
Please consult The X.Org Foundation support
        at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I am stumped and I don't know what to do to solve this issue, and still be able to use the proprietary drivers.

If it helps, I found this:

```
$ sudo aticonfig --list-adapters
* 0.00:01.0 AMD Radeon HD 7310 Graphics
```

Can anyone help me solve the issue? Thanks.

Edit: Here is my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`: http://ompldr.org/vaDFnbw

Edit2: I can manage to start X without the driver by disabling it (`sudo jockey-text -d kmod:fglrx`) but I still want to solve the issue and be able to use the proprietary drivers.

Comment: First...don't apt-get install fglrx.  Use jockey/jockey-gtk.  There are reports that it works when it is installed correctly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173481/amd-e1-1200-slow

Comment: There have been a few with problems installing fglrx in 12.10, many have had to install linux headers first `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`. Before installing fglrx. Your issue looks a little different but it can't harm

Comment: You could try the solution outlined here; http://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517