# Can I get online support from Canonical for improving performance?

Tags: performance, services, canonical

I am a real techno-tard. I need help optimizing my pc performance. Does Canonical offer any online support (such as online chat) to help people like me? I try to understand the posts but the language is just too technical for me to understand what to do to help myself.

Answer (score 1):

Related to support ,

They have lot of subject based [IRC Chat](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat) channels here as [Chat support IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat)

> There are several Internet relay chat (IRC) channels on the freenode
>   network (irc.freenode.net) used for Ubuntu support and development.
>
> The best place to start for general help with Ubuntu or just to meet
>   other Ubuntu users is #ubuntu or one of the many local language
>   channels.
>
> Specific channels are available for Ubuntu derivatives: #kubuntu,
>   edubuntu, #lubuntu and #xubuntu and separate channels relate to development, bugs,local community (LoCo) teams, accessibility and
>   documentation. Choose from the current [list of channels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat) .
>
> When participating in Ubuntu IRC channels, please follow the [code of
>   conduct.](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct)

Plus - [Gain enough Reputation to Chat](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/chat) on AU Chatroom itself.

Ubuntu also provides Paid support service, refer the [Canonical Profesional Desktop Support Service page](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/desktop#services).

As far as PC performance goes , you can try asking the question in detail description as required. Example

[How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)