# Xubuntu and Lubuntu based distro slow

Tags: xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I have a **Compaq Presario SR1950NX** desktop computer.

- AMD64 3800+ processor
- 1GB ram

It seems that Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu are all laggy. Things are slow, such as:

- clicking on menus
- opening programs
- The UI renders in pieces
- When using the browser the system slows down considerably

I ran the `top` command and I do notice that xorg hits 30% to 40% CPU when running the browsers.

I have tried these distros on a spare P4 machine and it is even worse. As long as I don't have a several things open at one time I can manage to get around although sluggishly.

Can anyone tell me what is it that I might be doing wrong? I have an integrated Nvidia card and have tried several of the recommended drivers which sometimes result in no boot screen upon reboot.