# All the applications take long to start - How to speed up?

Tags: 12.04, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I am experiencing a severe delay(about 20 to 30 secs, sometime about a minute) in applications getting started after clicking on it. For example,

- Opening home holder(nautilus)
- Opening firefox, chrome
- Opening a media file with VLC
- Opening a simple text file with gedit/geany

There has been no installation of any third party software in past one month, just the normal `Update manager` has run. Don't know why the response time of applications to start has been effected.

Is there any way I could speed up this on my machine? Please let me know if there are any tweaks I could do.

Comment: Some help with tags please !!!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04? Please add some detail. It would help others to help you.

Comment: have you tried everything here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance ?  it sounds like preload is exactly what you want (mentioned in the question and at least one answer)