# Intel i7 runs slow on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

My PC is a Intel core i7 (bought 3 months ago). I've tested code routines against a friend of mine who has an old intel core 2 duo and, to my surprise, his PC runs routines faster than mine.

Is there anything that may be causing this ?

Comment: Without telling us what tests you have run and what were the results, also what are other system components (memory, disk, graphic card etc), there is hardly anything that one can answer to that question.

Comment: I asked so vaguely hoping that this would be a known issue for which there could be a simple solution (install driver, update software, etc). 

We were on class learning C code. We had exactly the same code that would count all the prime numbers until a value determined by us. We calculated all the prime numbers until 1.000.000 with the time function so that we would know how long it took to run the code, and his computer had relatively better behavior than mine, with a much worse processor.

Comment: Is his code exactly the same as yours? Is it being compiled with the same compiler, and the same version of that compiler? Is it linking against exactly the same library implementation? Perhaps most importantly, *what else is running on each machine, when it is running*? Does the program use "100%" of all CPU time, on each machine?