# Ubuntu perfomance issues

Tags: 12.04, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I have as deafult Win 7 64b. But i get annoyed by some windows stuff so I decided to install ubuntu and learn Linux, because Win 8 is a nightmare. I have my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit installed in 100gb partition of my 1 Tb disc.

My problem is that my Ubuntu feel really slower than Win 7 - even though my Win 7 are after some years of usage and they became much slower. And Ubuntu is just installed OS - I just downloaded wine and skype. It takes some time for new window to appear (its not 10 seconds, but its really slower than my windows). Sometimes my donwload get stuck (in basic ubuntu app store)

Its just weird to me.

I thought its because of some drivers, but I am really new to linux, so I decided to ask some1 before I screw whole system up.

Specs: 
-6gbs of RAM - 3x2gb
-3.0 ghz CPU quadcore
-graphic card is HD4870 sapphire

Please excuse my poor english and my addiction to windows interface.

Pelda

Comment: I see that you've stated a problem. "Performance issues". So, is your question "How do I tweak Ubuntu for better performance?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use lots of tricks, but this are the two most effective:

- Install Preload, an app which improves Ubuntu's performance by speeding up the most used apps. [Click here](http://appnr.com/install/preload) to install it.
- Modify swappiness: this method uses the RAM for swap instead of the hard disk, this improves a lot the system's speed with 4 GB or more of RAM. To change it, open a terminal from the Dash, copy/paste `gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`, press <kbd>↵</kbd> and type your password. In the new window, change `vm.swappiness` to a number between 0 and 20. When lower, it will use more RAM. Simple, right?

Source: [Modify Ubuntu](http://modifyubuntu.com/#speed)

Comment: Nice, thank you for tips and for quick response !