# Performance tweaks for 12.10

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

I am running 12.10 on a Two year old Sony Vaio laptop (i7 with 8gb ram and ssd disk)

Overall performance nothing like as snappy as I would have expected. I am using the Nvidia proprietary driver. Might that impact performance?

Also fans on the laptop seem to be thrahing hard all the time.

Otherwise any quick tweaks that can be applied to make the machine fizz along a bit faster would be appreciated.

Thanks
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get install preload

This does cool stuff to enhance performance.

Write this stuff down first

Once on proprietary driver -> Go to nvidia.com. 
download and install the latest Linux driver -> (X will have to be off)

> sudo service lightdm -stop

That will kill X.
Navigate to Download directory and run

> sudo ./NVIDIAxxxxxxxx.sh

That should should would.
enable IOMMU in bios for 64bit/32bit support goodies.

Comment: Fantastic will give all of this a try and report back.