# ubuntu 12.10 running very slow on dell xps m1530

Tags: 12.10, dell, performance, xps

i am new to ubuntu and linux. i have installed 12.10 on my 32bit machine with 4gb's ram and Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T9300 @ 2.50GHz × 2 processor

takes a couple of seconds to open any application and can barely play video, very choppy and un-watchable

windows 7 and 8 run fine on this machine, maybe i am missing something, can anyone help?

Comment: let me know if you need any more info and i can supply it

Comment: You might find something useful here  http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance.

Comment: Try ubuntu-classic, directions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D I got a warning when trying to install 12.10 on my Dell XPS, pointing me to this url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 12.04 LTS without any problems on my m1530 with lesser specs (intel T8100). Do you use de propierty nvdia driver? If that doesn't help try out 12.04 LTS or go for 13.04. These are more stable releases than 12.10.

BTW try the 64bit version, than you profit from the full 4gb of ram