# Lubuntu is slower than Windows 7

Tags: lubuntu, 12.10, wubi, performance

I recently installed Lubuntu, and I noticed it runs slower than Windows 7. I know Lubuntu is said to be the most lightweight version of Ubuntu. Does anyone know then why it is so slow compared to Windows 7?

Specs:

- Laptop: Compaq Presario CQ57
- CPU: AMD C-50 (1 GHz, 1 MB Cache)
- RAM: 2GB
- GPU: ATI Radeon HD 6250 (256MB)

Additional hardware information:

```
ubuntu                    
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 1604MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD C-50 Processor
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1GHz
          capacity: 1GHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor ssse3 cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ibs skinit wdt arat hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 14h Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: latency=32
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6250]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:90400000-9043ffff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:19 ioport:5118(size=8) ioport:5124(size=4) ioport:5110(size=8) ioport:5120(size=4) ioport:5100(size=16) memory:90449000-904493ff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:90448000-90448fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:90447000-904470ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 42
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 40
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:16 memory:90440000-90443fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:90446000-90446fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:90300000-903fffff ioport:90000000(size=1048576)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: scsi2
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list scsi-host
                configuration: driver=rts_pstor latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:90300000-90300fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:3000(size=4096) ioport:90100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 05
                serial: 9c:8e:99:3b:2c:60
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:90104000-90104fff memory:90100000-90103fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 15.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:90200000-902fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 68:a3:c4:e8:df:ab
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.5.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90200000-90203fff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:90445000-90445fff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
             physical id: 16.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:90444000-904440ff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 43
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
```

Output of the requested commands:

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.6G       1.5G        67M         0B       463M       656M
-/+ buffers/cache:       416M       1.2G
Swap:         255M       8.9M       247M
 
 
ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.1  24440  2172 ?        Ss   07:33   0:02 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:06 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:02 [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:02 [migration/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:04 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [cpuset]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [khelper]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [netns]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [kblockd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [khubd]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [md]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        26  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:33 [kswapd0]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   07:33   0:00 [ksmd]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   07:33   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthre
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [crypto]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [binder]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [deferwq]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [charger_manage
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root       226  0.7  0.1  17896  3196 ?        Ss   07:33   1:44 mount.ntfs /dev
root       233  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:39 [loop0]
root       235  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:01 [jbd2/loop0-8]
root       236  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwri
root       423  0.0  0.0  17232   684 ?        S    07:33   0:00 upstart-udev-br
root       426  0.0  0.0  21864   980 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /sbin/udevd --d
102        499  0.0  0.0  24464  1620 ?        Ss   07:33   0:01 dbus-daemon --s
root       521  0.0  0.0  19168  1140 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluet
syslog     539  0.0  0.0 249472  1020 ?        Sl   07:33   0:02 rsyslogd -c5
root       542  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [krfcommd]
root       548  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       558  0.0  0.1  69656  2556 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
root       590  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       598  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [cfg80211]
root       623  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       633  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:00 [rts_pstor]
root       636  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    07:33   0:15 [rtsx-polling]
root       744  0.0  0.1  83308  2268 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem
root       764  0.0  0.3 266840  5180 ?        Ssl  07:33   0:03 NetworkManager
root       777  0.0  0.2 226436  4820 ?        Sl   07:33   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
root       786  0.0  0.0  15188   516 ?        S    07:33   0:00 upstart-socket-
root       828  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clea
root       871  0.0  0.0  31004   772 tty4     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       881  0.0  0.0  31004   772 tty5     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       885  0.0  0.1  31860  1644 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /sbin/wpa_suppl
root       897  0.0  0.0  31004   772 tty2     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       900  0.0  0.0  31004   772 tty3     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       901  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   07:33   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root       909  0.0  0.0  31004   772 tty6     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       934  0.0  0.0  19112   812 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 cron
daemon     935  0.0  0.0  16908   188 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 atd
whoopsie   938  0.0  0.2 204320  4020 ?        Ssl  07:33   0:00 whoopsie
root       949  0.0  0.0  21116   528 ?        Ss   07:33   0:01 /usr/sbin/irqba
root       996  0.0  2.0 283236 33768 ?        SLsl 07:33   0:00 lightdm
root      1080  0.0  0.0  31004   768 tty1     Ss+  07:33   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1084  3.0  2.2 147616 37780 tty7     Ss+  07:33   6:55 /usr/bin/X :0 -
root      1093  0.0  0.2 203360  4004 ?        Sl   07:33   0:00 /usr/lib/accoun
root      1103  0.0  0.1  10192  3000 ?        S    07:33   0:00 /sbin/dhclient
root      1111  0.0  0.2 1043092 3768 ?        Sl   07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/conso
nobody    1214  0.0  0.0  44100  1436 ?        S    07:33   0:02 /usr/sbin/dnsma
root      1221  0.0  0.2 222156  4240 ?        Sl   07:33   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
root      1302  0.0  0.1 104740  2692 ?        Ss   07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
root      1322  0.0  0.0 104740  1432 ?        S    07:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
root      1453  0.0  0.2 171636  4328 ?        Sl   07:33   0:00 lightdm --sessi
1000      1499  0.0  0.4 383220  7264 ?        Ssl  07:34   0:00 /usr/bin/lxsess
1000      1532  0.0  0.0  24420   604 ?        S    07:34   0:00 dbus-launch --a
1000      1533  0.0  0.0  12488   320 ?        Ss   07:34   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-ag
1000      1534  0.0  0.0  23808   444 ?        Ss   07:34   0:00 //bin/dbus-daem
1000      1537  0.0  0.0  24420   608 ?        S    07:34   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
1000      1538  0.0  0.0  24676  1464 ?        Ss   07:34   0:00 //bin/dbus-daem
1000      1543  0.0  0.2 259220  4056 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
1000      1550  0.0  0.1 208856  2996 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      1554  0.0  0.2 357636  3952 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//
1000      1561  0.1  0.5 168812  8628 ?        S    07:34   0:14 openbox --confi
1000      1564  0.6  1.2 623152 19976 ?        Sl   07:34   1:28 lxpanel --profi
1000      1565  0.0  0.1  79440  2960 ?        S    07:34   0:03 xscreensaver -n
1000      1569  0.0  1.2 689324 21076 ?        Sl   07:34   0:08 pcmanfm --deskt
1000      1572  0.0  1.0 462824 16956 ?        Sl   07:34   0:01 /usr/lib/policy
1000      1574  0.0  0.6 398608 11272 ?        Sl   07:34   0:02 update-notifier
1000      1576  0.0  1.0 650064 17728 ?        Sl   07:34   0:01 nm-applet
1000      1581  0.0  0.2 364708  4212 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi
1000      1586  0.0  0.7 396376 11544 ?        Ssl  07:34   0:00 xfce4-power-man
1000      1587  0.0  0.0  23808  1512 ?        S    07:34   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemo
1000      1589  0.0  0.2 134016  3816 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
1000      1594  0.0  0.2 124632  3304 ?        Sl   07:34   0:02 /usr/lib/at-spi
1000      1598  0.0  0.1  47492  2460 ?        S    07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
1000      1603  0.0  0.3 235476  5472 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1608  0.0  0.3 356044  5196 ?        Sl   07:34   0:07 /usr/lib/udisks
1000      1619  0.0  0.1 214436  3020 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      1623  0.0  0.1 298488  3124 ?        Sl   07:34   0:01 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      1633  0.0  0.1  68004  2480 ?        S    07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
1000      1635  0.0  0.1 126472  2560 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      1642  0.0  0.3 426460  4948 ?        Sl   07:34   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64
ntp       1679  0.0  0.1  37688  2248 ?        Ss   07:34   0:02 /usr/sbin/ntpd
1000      3253  0.0  0.2 299772  4328 ?        Sl   08:14   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
1000      3287  0.0  0.1 261996  2600 ?        Sl   08:14   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/
1000      4439  0.8  2.7 969736 44712 ?        Sl   08:41   1:27 /usr/bin/python
root      4625  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    08:59   0:11 [kworker/0:1]
root      5041  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:08   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root      5042  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:14   0:01 [kworker/1:1]
root      5044  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:14   0:00 [kworker/u:1]
root      5045  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:15   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root      5049  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:15   0:00 [flush-8:0]
1000      5051  6.8  4.4 665952 73132 ?        Sl   11:15   0:35 chromium-browse
1000      5053  0.1  0.4 268344  6792 ?        S    11:15   0:00 chromium-browse
1000      5054  0.0  0.0   6464   404 ?        S    11:15   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
1000      5055  0.0  0.9 282288 16152 ?        S    11:15   0:00 chromium-browse
1000      5059  0.0  0.3 290484  5204 ?        S    11:15   0:00 chromium-browse
root      5093  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:15   0:00 [flush-7:0]
1000      5100  9.7  4.2 914988 70128 ?        Sl   11:16   0:43 /usr/lib/chromi
root      5119  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:19   0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root      5120  0.0  0.0  21860   784 ?        S    11:20   0:00 /sbin/udevd --d
root      5121  0.0  0.0  21860   392 ?        S    11:20   0:00 /sbin/udevd --d
root      5125  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:20   0:00 [kworker/u:0]
1000      5126  3.8  3.5 898964 58320 ?        Sl   11:21   0:06 /usr/lib/chromi
root      5141  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:22   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
1000      5143  2.4  0.9 456260 15812 ?        Rl   11:23   0:01 lxterminal
1000      5144  0.0  0.0  14788   808 ?        S    11:23   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
1000      5145  0.2  0.1  36932  2920 pts/2    Ss   11:23   0:00 /bin/bash
root      5200  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:24   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
1000      5201  0.0  0.0  33628  1292 pts/2    R+   11:24   0:00 ps aux
 
 
mount
/dev/loop0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda2 on /host type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/the_paladin/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=the_paladin)
 
 
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       18G  4.7G   12G  29% /
udev            794M  4.0K  794M   1% /dev
tmpfs           321M  896K  320M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            803M  132K  803M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       219G  163G   57G  75% /host
```

Comment: I find it very weird, specially since I have tested several different PCs with Lubuntu/Xubuntu and Windows. Anyway, can you provide what version of Lubuntu you are using, cpu, memory, hdd, etc..

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using the latest version of Lubuntu, by the way.

Comment: Memory: 1642MB(761MB used)

Comment: Type lshw in the terminal and it should give all the information needed. Copy all of that to a pastebin site for example then post the link here. I'll add the information to your question so it helps other Ubuntu readers try to solve your problem.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/m7VL6TPv)

Comment: Can you define slow? Can you give examples, I have never heard of this.

Comment: @Paladin Please edit the original question and add the new information there, so that others don't have to go through a long chain of comments to benefit from your question.

Comment: Also your system specs look 'OK' but you may have to turn off some of the more demanding background processes.  Can you pastie the output of `free -h`, `ps aux`, `mount`, and `df -h`. Also did you install in any odd way like wubi?

Comment: @cotery: Slow as in almost all the apps I have run much much slower than Windows 7 and the operating system itself is laggy. And yes, I did indeed install from wubi. This is because at the time I wasn't sure if it would install off of a DVD.

Comment: [stuff coteyr asked for](http://pastebin.com/sFL9CUAz)

Comment: @coteyr: Along with what I said, for example, the game called Minecraft and another game like it that runs much faster on Windows 7 called Block Story run much less than half the speed as their Windows versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the only things I see that would cause "slowness" are a couple of your mount points.

> /dev/sda2 on /host type fuseblk
>   gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/the_paladin/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse

/dev/sda2 should probably be mounted via fstab using a kernel level driver instead of via fuse. You should be able to mount an ntfs partition (guessing) via fstab without using fuse. (I do not know if this will break wubi installs)

That may gain you some speed, specially if you accessing any data on /host.

Now your two examples are a different matter. If memory serves Minecraft is Java. You can try different java versions (like sun v.s. OpenJDK) or try some command line arguments. [This post may help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1701501)

Block Story I don't recognize.

Wubi however will result in a much slower system then a native install. Usually the bottle neck is around disk access. [More details](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_wubi_1010&num=1) at that link.

TL;DR; if you want the best performance don't use wubi. When benchmarking make sure to use something objective. [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) is generally well liked. Run it in both Linux and windows then use that data to decide which is faster in what areas. Using games as your benchmark is not going to give you a good idea.

Comment: How do I do the first thing you said? Mount /dev/sda2 to fstab how?

Comment: You using wubi, so I don't *know* that it's safe. But `/dev/sda2 /host ntfs-3g defaults 0 0` added to /etc/fstab should do the trick.

Comment: If I reinstall Lubuntu from a DVD, will I loose all the stuff that is already on my wubi Lubuntu?

Comment: If it's not backed up, based on your configuration, yes.

Comment: I don't understand how to install the Sun Java onto my 12.10 Lubuntu