# 12.04 LTS running slow

Tags: 12.04

I moved on the Ubuntu a few month ago. At the begining I was flyging with this system. However, it becomes running too slow nevertheles there is no additional problem or loading to system. At this point, do you have any solution, or recommendition to get more stable?

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance) out.