# Ubuntu EXTREMELY slow on MacMini

Tags: performance

So I have an older MacMini. It's not the world's greatest machine, but it doesn't suck that badly:

Intel® Core™2 CPU T5600 @ 1.83GHz × 2, 1gig ram

I have installed Ubuntu on MUCH weaker machines with acceptable performance. I have installed Windows 7 on this machine with acceptable performance. But Ubuntu 12.04? SLOW. Horribly slow. Loading the system dialog is a 45 second affair. Starting chrome is a 2 minute affair. Launching Ubuntu Software Center? 5+ minutes. Something obviously isn't doing what it's supposed to be.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Which GPU does your Mac mini use?, if Ubuntu isn't cutting it for you try other variants, Xubuntu, Lubuntu.

Comment: Intel GMA 950 using 64 MB of DDR2 SDRAM, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini

Comment: I installed Xubuntu, and it seems to work a bit better, though it is still slower than I would expect. Will try Lubuntu later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and found a quick, simple and very effective performance.

Have a look at cat /proc/cpuinfo and see if your CPU is not being underclocked. I downloaded the simple scale.sh script and ran it with the performance switch and got an amazing improvement. An alternative would be to use something like indicator-cpufreq app.

Comment: Where did you get the simple scale.sh script? Where would the OP get indicator-cpufreq app and what does it do? this is all useful information.