# What can I do when Ubuntu 12.10 begins to work slow?

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

As stated in the title, I want to know how can I repair my existing OS, Ubuntu 12.10.
It seems to be very slow, earlier I installed it along side Windows XP (32-Bit) at that time it was working fine. But now its very slow. And I've removed Windows XP.

Is there any way I can repair it? Or I've to re-install it completely?

---

Features of my PC:

**Processor:** `Intel Core 2 Duo 2.20 E4500`
**Motherboard:** `ASUS P5KPL-AM`
**RAM:** `2GB`
**GPU:** `Nvdia GeForce 9500 GT 512MB`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What exactly is slow? The bootup process, starting a certain application, graphics, etc. Also include more details about what the bottleneck might be. Start by running System Monitor to see if some application is using all resources.

Comment: Bootup process and loading of applications is slow. As for application, when I click the icon, after 4-5 seconds it loads up.

Answer (score 1):

check you boot up service and install BUM (Boot Up manager)

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

install ubuntu tweak and try janitor to clear cache files

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

try to install preload service

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

I hope these tips may be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll let you know after installing these.

Comment: ok i waiting for you !