# X server without Unity

Tags: unity, xbmc, xserver

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on a Gigabyte BRIX and serving as a HTPC (plugged into my television through a HDMI connection)

My question is pretty simple, is it possible to start Ubuntu without the Unity desktop and still be able to launch graphical applications such as XBMC ?

Comment: Does this help you out? See [Start ubuntu without a desktop environment but start an X application](http://askubuntu.com/q/310671/88802)

Comment: I confirm it's a duplicate. Thanks for the link !