# open program in xsession from command line environment

Tags: command-line, compiz, xserver

I just wondered if some old computers laying around here could still be used for some games if I completely cut off the display manager. Is there a way to start a gui program from the command line in a new (and only) Xsession, even without lxde? I doubt it doesn't need compiz, but can I somehow configure it to only show that window?

If there is, is it still easy to have at least a small border (or frame or something like that) with a cross to terminate and close the Xserver?
I'd like to use it eg. for Minecraft or Starbound.

Thanks!
-Peter

Comment: Try `startx openbox`, openbox is lightweight window manager

Comment: @Sneetsher: I actually look for some command or script to start it like `startx openbox "/path/to/program"`, adapting to your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found >[Start ubuntu without a desktop environment but start an X application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application)< to be helpful here.

The best answer works for me - exept, when I put the path `/media/myusername/I/have/it/on/another/partition/linux64/starbound` in, it doesn't show up to choose. I read the `tryExec=` field looks, if the program is present, else it is ignored. It is not required though, so I'll try without that next.

**UPDATE:** I figured it out somehow. I played around a little, and it appears that it won't read the `/usr/share/xsessions` files, since their owner is root.
I had places a .sh script there to mount the partition, too, if not already aviable, but I moved it into `~/bin` and now it works fine with that.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You may declare a shell function that modifies `autostart` file and launch `openbox-session` instead.

This will show 2 windows one for target GUI program and an `xterm` for `openbox`. To kill the xsession, close that xterm window.

```
obox () {
  echo "$@ &" > ~/.config/openbox/autostart;
  startx openbox-session;
}
```

Example:

```
obox gedit ~/.config/openbox/autostart
obox winecfg
```

Comment: Hm, it would work as workaround for me, but unforunaly, now I can't use lightdm anymore. Do you have an idea what went wrong? Instead of starting a session lightdm comes up again, almost immediately.

Comment: could you add more information about you environment, are you using lubuntu, which release... try running same command from any  console tty1-6.

Comment: Oh, found it. `chown myusername:myusername ~/.Xauthority` works. Well, your suggestion would be a workaround at least.