# Basic desktop environment

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-environments, window-manager

I have installed a new operating system with no GUI desktop environment at all because 99% of my programs don't use a graphical interface, but I would like something basic for the remaining 1% of my programs that use a graphical interface. No menu, no top bar, just the bare minimum to have a graphical program running in it.

I was hoping for something like LXDE but without all the bloatware.

Comment: I was hoping for something like LXDE but without all the bloatware.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: [Start ubuntu without a desktop environment but start an X application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get more lightweight than LXDE by using just a window manager like fluxbox, openbox, i3-wm or awesome from the default Ubuntu repositories instead of a desktop environment.

To install Fluxbox and a few additional packages like in the below screenshot, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install lightdm xorg fluxbox catfish eterm hsetroot xloadimage fbautostart fbpager wm-icons
sudo reboot
```

[image]

Comment: Openbox is great, doesn't have that steep of a learning curve too. I've used for quite some time on my old Toshiba L455D. There's also Blackbox, from which i believe Openbox was derived. Also quite a lovely choice

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you check out the i3wm (i3 window manager).
Apps fill the screen by default, and it is highly customizable.
[Here is a good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1I63wGcvU4).

Comment: Note: i3 is a tiling wm. So windows are "tiled" on screen

Comment: This is probably the best option to this user. A pity this answer is so minimalistic.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa well it answered the question.But i would be happy to provide further details if you like.

Comment: Check out [How to Answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer).