# Ubuntu with no window manager 95% of time

Tags: xserver, nas

I want to run Ubuntu on a dedicated NAS I am building.

95% of the time I want to run it in as low power mode as possible (although I do want to run Crashplan on it), so I'd like to disable most X services and therefore the X window manager environment.

However sometimes when I log in, instead of using ssh, I'd quite like the ability to run the window manager and have a (Unity?) desktop.  Is there an easy way to achieve all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a simple window manager into Ubuntu Server, and start it only when you need it. I think it might be enough to install `fluxbox, xinit, xterm` (and the packages that they want)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install fluxbox xinit xterm
```

and you can start the graphical window manager with

```
startx
```

The following link is describing a system, where this is available via a text mode menu

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

but you can do it manually like it is described in this answer.

Comment: I like fluxbox too. Here are links to 2 screenshots of fluxbox running in Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/835609/basic-desktop-environment/835632#835632 http://i.imgur.com/vRsx9EH.png

Comment: That's great - thank you. Will mark as correct once I've had a chance to experiment