# Firefox plugin doesn't work in Custom xsession

Tags: session, firefox-extensions

I am trying to create an **Ubuntu Browser only** session using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application).

Everything works fine with this setup. However, I also want to disable file downloads in this setup so I used firefox [publicfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/public-fox/) plugin for the same. But for some reason this plugin doesn't work in this browser only session (It works perfectly fine in normal Lubuntu session)

What is the issue and How to resolve it?