# how to boot without desktop environment?

Tags: boot, desktop-environments

I had installed Lubuntu in my old computer. It's so old that I think I should not use any desktop environment.

Is there any way to boot without Any desktop environment? I had only Lubuntu on my computer thus I didn't install grub or boot loader. I don't want to remove the desktop environment for testing reasons or start single application as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application). I want to boot into my Lubuntu normally, just without any desktop environment (e.g: LXDE), I want it like Ubuntu server.

Comment: Then try the Openbox session? That option should be available at login time.

Comment: I had to go for puppy linux now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your system is running use:

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

If you were happy with what you've got, set multi-user as your default systemd target:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Alternatively you can kill the "X" or disable display manger service...

Comment: To reverse the choice: `systemctl set-default graphical.target
`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just enter runlevel 3 as default. if you are using systemd you can do this:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default runlevel3.target
```

or:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Comment: It's just a symbolic link... right? ;)

Comment: Yes. they both point to same thing.