# Ubuntu 13.04 extremely slow

Tags: 13.04

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop ( intel 1.6 GHz dual core processor, 512mb ram) It's a dual boot with xp.
Its booting time is okay but it is extremely slow while doing normal tasks (like opening firefox or terminal or any other thing). Its 3D effects are also hanging. 
Can anyone please suggest what should I do to increase its speed.

Comment: It's because of your ram. Do you created any swap space?

Comment: @NewBil Yes while installing I allocated about 1gb swap space

Comment: If it possible than by more ram otherwise if you want to use Ubuntu like distro than follow prophecy201 answer below..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu with Unity needs more CPU-Power and RAM.
Your system has not enough ressources to run Ubuntu and Unity smoothly.

Maybe you have a better experience with Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are made for systems with less performance.

Comment: I agree. Both variants performs smoother on lower end computers.

Comment: Can i fall back to Xubuntu or Lubuntu from ubuntu?

Comment: I think Xubuntu will be better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've installed xubuntu and it is running fine

Answer (score 1):

Can you add more memory? 512MB is not optimal. How much memory/swap are being used if you run `top` or `htop`? Running LXDE may help as well.

Comment: I'm a first time linux user and have just used it since 2-3 days I don't know how to use top or htop. Can you please elaborate @Bert

Comment: [This page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/) will show you how to install and run `htop`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed 12.04 before? I have the same problem with 13.04 when old works fine. I am just using it as a file server. so my GPU is old. But with an  i7 920 (oc'd to 4GHz watercooled)  with 12GB RAM.

12.04 work no problem for me and I need to use GNOME fallback desktop for 13.04

I think there is a problem with drivers for you Graphics Card.

Comment: No i have never used linux before. I'll try to search for drivers thanks