# how do I install a network manager on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, software-installation, downloads

I uninstalled my network manager trying to fix a problem.  Now I have no network manager and therefore no internet.  So I need one and I need to install it?

Comment: I edited my answer taking into consideration you do not have an internet connection.

Comment: Side-note for those looking at this only to create a VPN connection: In my case, I did not need the network-manager. I had an ovpn file ready. I could import it as a new vpn in the networks settings.

Answer (score 21):

I did not realize the OP could not connect to the internet. You don't need a network manager to connect to the internet. Don't waste your time looking for a different computer and transferring the files. If you have an Ethernet cable connect the computer directly to the modem and then:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Append the following lines to the end of the file:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`Ctrl+X` to exit and `Y` to save. Then:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

You should get an internet connection. If you do not have a DHCP server use the following instead (if you don't know if you have a DHCP server, then you probably have one so nevermind the following):

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Replacing the address, netmask and gateway values with the ones you are used to.

If you cannot possibly connect the computer directly to the modem, you can also manually connect to a wireless AP, though [it's much more complicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal).

After connecting to the internet:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

or `wicd` instead of `network-manager` - it's the one I use.

If you are not on the sudoers list issue `su` to become root and then do all the commands without `sudo`.

Comment: `su` needs a root password to be set, which is not set by default, and most new users wouldn't know how to set it, and shouldn't really need to. Why become true root when you have your friendly neighborhood `sudo`? I never advise anyone to become true root unless absolutely needed, and I would do it by `sudo -i`, not `su`.

Comment: @Alaa I advise it because of two reasons: First, one might not be on the sudoers list, which is the default for non-root users in a lot of distributions. Second, you don't have to type `sudo` all the time. I'm used with Debian, and Debian-based distributions usually have a root password set on installation by default, if I remember correctly that was the case on Ubuntu too, at least on earlier versions.

Comment: @Alex you didn't try what @Alaa said: `sudo -i` gives (if really needed) a true root shell.

Comment: my /etc/network/interfaces file informs me that ifupdown has been replaced by /etc/netplan ...

Answer (score 11):

To install NetworkManager that is installed by default when you installed Ubuntu,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Thanks to vasa1, I failed to see the no internet part.  So what you can do is visit [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/network-manager), from a machine that has Internet connectivity (friend's, work, etc.) go down to the bottom of the page, and download Network Manager that corresponds to your Ubuntu version and architecture (32, or 64 bit), (in my case its for 13.04 Raring) and once downloaded, take it over to your system, and install it from the downloaded file.

Comment: But OP doesn't have an internet connection now. So how would `sudo apt-get install network-manager`work (unless the relevant debs are in `/var/cache/apt/archives`)?

Answer (score 4):

Happened to face same problem. That's how i solved it. I happened to remove the network-manager and yep now I have no internet. So I came to know after that best shot is http://packages.ubuntu.com/. So but which package I asked myself.

So what i did i executed command again
`sudo apt-get install network-manager.`

**Its obvious it fails, but I came to know what package it was trying to download.**
e.g in my case if failed while downloading `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/network-manager-gnome_0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3_amd6`. So that's it, go to your friend system. Hit this url .It will download deb package.

Now copy this package and paste it in /var/cache/apt/archives. And now run again `sudo apt-get install network-manager` and that's it.

I am hoping all dependencies are already there. So by this way you can install network manager without using any boot device

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is boot from an installation media and then use `chroot`.

- Boot from an ubuntu installation media.
- Mount your system drives: `sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt`
- `chroot` into your system: `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
- Install networkmanager with `sudo apt-get install network-manager`
- Reboot your system