# I don't have a system network service

Tags: internet

I run a sudo command like

```
sudo apt-get remove network manager
```

after this network manager removed. how to get back?

Comment: Do you still have the installation media you used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: yes. but that's old version 14.04

Comment: current version is 16.04

Comment: Do you have a wired connection to the router?

Comment: yes. but establishing network to ubuntu failed.

Comment: Try following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/319803/682481) to restore Network manager.

Comment: Let us know if that works, and I'll add it as an answer below.

Comment: there I failed to connect with ethernet.

Comment: now I am trying to went to boot from cd from pc start up. and will find to repair. if tgat works.

Comment: problem is its 14.04 whether currently have 16.04