# Unity environment way too slow in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, performance

Unity and its apps open too slowly whenever I open one. It takes a while for them to appear completely. Everything works properly when the window is already open. The biggest problem is with the dash: it's SO SLOW when I'm looking for an app although I have removed some lenses.

What should I do or what can I do? These issues only occur with Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 whereas 12.04 works AMAZNGLY but I have issues when updating a package or installing a new one, that's why I don't opt for that one.

Specifications: RAM: 2GB, Processor: Intel® Atom™ CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz × 4, Graphics card: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)

Comment: Please, could you post that as answer instead?

Comment: Which package do you have problems to update or to install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Comment: Seeing this: > Graphics card: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits), I think it could be some gpu driver issue, please find out the gpu model, and google about installing the correct driver for the model on 13.10 and later.

Comment: I have the same problem with Dash and no tweaks helped rendering it faster. One thing which does help is using Super + A instead of just Super to open applications. I like Unity but due to this slowness I moved to Gnome 3 for the time being and am loving it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too. Re-installed 13.10, same result. Then I remembered to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras which solved the very slow desktop.Run the below command on terminal to install **ubuntu-restricted-extras**,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the performance of your computer. Some computers can't handle 13.04-13.10 as well as they did 12.04. (I've also seen the reverse happen in many cases)

At any rate, there is a tool in the default repositories called *Unity Tweak Tool* that adjusts the visual effects of Unity however you want. A lot of these adjustments increase performance, and make it so that it doesn't run super-slow.

You can find *Unity Tweak Tool* in the Software Center, or you can directly install it with Terminal by pressing *CTRL+ALT+T*, and typing `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`