# I only have 1GB of ram, what can I do to improve the performance on my 32-bit 14.04 system?

Tags: 14.04, performance, ram, memory-usage

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu on an old iMac. It was going painfully slow on OSX so I wiped that and installed Ubuntu overtop of it hoping it would speed things up a bit.

I'm not going to be doing any hardcore gaming or anything, but I just wish it wouldn't become almost unresponsive whenever an album of gifs starts loading.

What are some tricks to speed up the computer and use less ram? Thanks in advance.

Specs:

```
Memory: 983.1 MiB
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7300 @ 2.00GHz x 2   
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV610    
OS type: 32-bit   
Disk: 245 GB
```

Comment: Related: [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/q/2194/22949)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), which is an [official Ubuntu derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) that uses the more lightweight [Xfce desktop environment](http://xfce.org/).

I did and it really works good! :)