# Ubuntu 14.04 Slow Performance

Tags: 14.04, graphics, performance

I'm somewhat new to Linux and Ubuntu so please be patient with me.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the performance is very slow. The computer (a desktop) boots at a normal speed, but OS usage is slow. When using Ubuntu, all animations are slow. It can take several long seconds to open/close processes. I'm thinking this has to do with the default graphics driver but am not sure what to do about it. As a side note, I had Ubuntu 11 installed on it earlier the performance speed was fine.

My stats according to the details screen are:
Memory 1.2 GiB
Processor Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
Graphics Gallium 0.4 on NV32
OS type 32-bit
Disk 77.3 GB

Please also keep in mind that I do my research before asking questions on the internet. I have already done a reasonable amount of research on the issue and have found nothing that solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't particularly clear on your hardware setup, but a P4 with a GeForce2 (I think that's what the NV32 means here) is a thirteen year-old computer system. First of all, while that's officially above the minimum specs for Ubuntu, it's terribly slow compared even to a 2007 computer. You need to accept that fact.

The graphics card is quite old, and unsupported by NVidia. Your slow graphics are probably due to an accelerated driver not being installed. I think you can install the nvidia-96 driver to get acceleration, but you still shouldn't expect something wonderfully snappy.

Honestly, your system is more appropriate for [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (or maybe Xubuntu or Ubuntu Mate). The system will respond much better on these OSes.

Comment: slow is subjection and in general is due to a poorly compatible driver. Although it could be the graphics card, it could also be a with a wireless driver as well. +1 to almost any alternate windowmanager, kubuntu, xubuntu, or lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I installed Lubuntu and the computer has normal performance speeds!

Comment: The compress-RAM trick here is quite useful for systems with only 1 or 2 gb of RAM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance