# Speeding properly Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Could you tell me if there is some steps to take to make ubuntu 14.04 faster?

Comment: What are your computer's specs? It might be better to install Lubuntu instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)

Comment: Depends , speed is subjective and many issues contiibute to "slow" most result when running poorly supported hardware. I would start by purchasing a computer with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can try to speed it up. The one I would most recommend is to replace the Unity environment with GNOME. To do this:

1. Install MATE desktop by running this in Terminal: `sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment`.
2. Once it's done installing, log out. There should now be a gear icon in the top right corner of the password area.
3. Click this gear and select the MATE desktop environment before logging in.