# how to speed up performance in gnome-shell?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, graphics, performance, gnome-shell

I run ubuntu with Gnome-shell as desktop and I have a laggy desktop. So I would like to make a smooth desktop like in that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkRzIjhTGUw). The user runs archlinux with a modded versione of mutter.

In that question I mean that the user interface (gnome-shell) animations run laggy.

My config: 
AMD Athlon x4 860k - nVidia GTX 1050 ti 4GB - 16 GB RAM DDR3

I should not have issues with performance.

Has anyone a good solution to fix that issue ?

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)

Comment: "all of us that run ubuntu with gnome-shell as desktop manager got a laggy desktop." probably not true as a general remerk. At least for me, it is not lagyg.

Comment: @vanadium - I mean that animations are not smoothly

Comment: I fully agree that this might be the case for you. However, you are generalizing. It is not that because it is laggy for you that it will be for "all of us". I would suggest to change that first sentence. For sure it will be an issue with the graphics card and drivers. Perhaps you may try different resolutions.

Comment: @vanadium you are right, but, in my experience with gnome-shell i didn't get smooth animations like in the video i link above, did you see that ? if you not, watch it and then you understand what i mean.

Comment: However, they talk about a workaround of mutter that can run smoothly gnome (and all other desktop that run over it)

Comment: I am only commenting about the fact that your first sentence is wrong: you say "all of us". That is not correct. Not everybody has the issue.

Comment: @vanadium - so if your desktop runs smoothly and every animations are smoothly, say me your configurations please.