# Slow Performance of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have no issue with Ubuntu 18.04 booting. However the apps on ubuntu takes too long to start at the beginning. Even the nautilus file manager takes too long after booting of ubuntu freshly. I have enough storage but still facing such laggy performances. can anyone help??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please post details of your system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-ubuntu-overall-system-performance)