# How to configure to record data to pendrive instantly?

Tags: 10.10, usb-drive

If I edit the files on my pendrive, and then just remove it physically, the data will not be recorded. I have to click "eject", and so the led starts to blink, and the data starts to be recorded.

How can I change this, so that the data is recorded instantly when changed?

**update: Ubuntu 11.10**

In Ubuntu 11.10 I wrote the rules file (from *@enzotib* answer), and works, but gives the following message when I try to eject/unmount:

[image]

(should I start another question for Ubuntu 11.10?)

Comment: Performance will be less as the write cache is not used anymore. Properly unmount partitions using the eject / unmount options or you'll lose data.

Comment: You can use the `sync` option when mounting the partition. This is not recommended though as it dramatically increases the number of writes to the thumbdrive.

Comment: @arrange as ubuntu do the automount, is there a way to put this `sync` as default, so I don't need to do this in a terminal every time? And I'm aware that it'll dramatically increase the number of writes, still is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/30762/is-setting-default-mount-options-for-udisks-really-not-possible

Comment: @arrange saw it, but it's still not a complete answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the [question (and answer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30762/is-setting-default-mount-options-for-udisks-really-not-possible) that @arrange shows in his comment, let's create a new file

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules
```

and write into it the following content (see [udev::Mount under /media; use partition label if present](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mount_under_.2Fmedia.3B_use_partition_label_if_present))

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime,sync"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002"

# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

I have done some little modifications with respect to that reported on the website

- added the `sync` option to `ENV{mount_options}`
- modified the `gid=100` option to `uid=1000,gid=1000`, where the number are relative to your used-id and group-id, as returned by `id -u` and `id -g`

The second one make you the owner of all files on the mounted partition, so no permission problem can arise. Obviously this is not the case if more than a single user should access the files, but this can be handled in other ways.

For non-windows filesystems, owner and group are metadata on the filesystem, and cannot be changed by a mount option.

The new rule is immediately active (*udev* uses *inotify* to detect new and modified rule files).

The mounted drive is not automatically opened in a file manager window, as you can see, and this is difficult to achieve, given that the mounting process is owned by root, and do not have access to your graphical login session. But the drive is on your desktop, so a simple double-click will open it.

Unfortunately I cannot get the desktop right-click unmount to work, but this is not a big problem: having the `sync` option in place, you can simply unplug the device, and the udev rule take care of removing the entry from `/proc/mounts` and removing the mount-point.

Comment: I couldn't get round to writing this how-to, thanks for doing it ;) And I also couldn't get the user unmount to work, it seems like the `users` option is only valid in the `fstab` file... This isn't a problem here ("sync"), but for a general how-to it would be.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, after doing the described, I couldn't create, edit or delete any files on the pendrive. Also, it's no more automatically opening the window when I plug it. Any idea?

Comment: By the way, I considered that the extension you typed ".rule" is wrong, and I used the same of the other files on that folder: ".rules".

Comment: The documentation do not talk about specific extensions to use. By the way I copied wrong from the site, so it is better to use `.rules` to be safe. For the rest, see the edited answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 now, and there's a different behavior. Please, see my update.

Comment: @TomBrito: from the last paragraph of my answer you can understand that I think it should not work not event in 10.10.

Comment: I had some trouble the last days with my "home" asking to mount when it was already mounted in the boot. I suspect this script may be related. As I don't understand it, maybe you want to review it?

Answer (score 0):

For the newer Ubuntu (> 20.04) you can create/edit /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf and set:

```
[defaults]
defaults=noatime,sync
```

And

```
sudo service udisks2 restart
```

the disconnect and reconnect your disk.

This make **sync** all filesystem automounted and ignore creation time (speed up navigation file system)