# revert/change automount settings in 12.10

Tags: udisks

I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, and now my disk automount as /media/**user**/*uuid*

When I was on 12.04, it was simply /media/*uuid* [uuid or label], and I would like to change it back.

syslog:

```
Oct 21 23:08:53 dv6 udisksd[2562]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/matt/1Dxxxxxxxxxx2CA1 on behalf of uid 1000
```

However if I umount, and run

`udisks --mount /dev/sdc1`

it then mounts as /media/1Dxxxxxxxxxx2CA1, which is exactly what I want.  I looked for some kind of udisksd conf file, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Rather stupidly, you have to go and create a new file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

I called mine `20-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules` instead of 11-media... but up to you, and wrote the configuration file at [How to configure to record data to pendrive instantly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61448/how-to-configure-to-record-data-to-pendrive-instantly)

This seemed to solve the problem for me, anyway.