# How to mount disc with exec permissions

Tags: mount, permissions

I have a storage drive I normally mount just clicking on the disc in the file browser.  However, I want to be able to run some bash scripts from that drive. When I try `./script.sh` I get Permission Denied. How can I set it up so I can run scripts from this drive?

Comment: What filesystem is used on the drive in question?

Comment: @dobey I'm pretty sure its NTFS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Work Around

There is a simple work around, instead of `./script.sh`, do

```
sh script.sh
```

Or

```
bash script.sh
```

You should check the first line of script.sh to confirm which shell to use.

### Manual Mount

Mount with command line, you can use the `exec` option as follow

```
mount -o exec <device> <mount-point/path>

mount -o exec /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

If the disc is automounted, you will have to un-mount(not eject) it with file manager first.

### udisk

This is the complicated way and is answered in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/62508/106529).

Comment: No good, the script also tries to call other scripts and stuff getting permission denied.

Comment: You may want to use the manual mount method.

Comment: How do I know my arguments, usually the drive is called /media/Media  not sure where to get the equivilent of /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom

Comment: To check your cdrom/dvdrom dev path, put in a disc, wait for it to automount, then in a terminal type "mount", it should show up in the list. Possibiliteis: `/dev/sr0`

Comment: The second arguments is actually just any empty folder you created beforehand. Common ones to use are `/mnt/cdrom`, `/media/cdrom`

Comment: @JohnSiu, does someone need to unmount the USB that has the files before mounting again to the new mount point? can they leave the automounted point mounted and mount to a new point? I do this and for some reason files still lack the executable permissions option.