# How to increase HDD write speeds

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ext4, rsync

I have 2x `Seagate Barracuda 1TB 1000GB 7200RPM  64MB SATA3` HDs in an ubuntu 16.04 server (`Dell Poweredge 400SC`).

When copying files using `rsync` from one disk to another I'm getting speeds of 25-30 Mb/s. From reading it would appear I should be able to achieve double that.

How should I go about optimising this setup to increase the transfer speed?

```
// lsblk

sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   931G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   509M  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    20G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 910.5G  0 part /mnt
```

I've read about enabling DMA, but it appears I don't seem to be able to do this on the system.

```
// hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   1098 MB in  2.00 seconds = 548.31 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 346 MB in  3.02 seconds = 114.69 MB/sec
```

Trying to enable DMA on `sdb` does the following.

```
// hdparm -d1 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting using_dma to 1 (on)
 HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

// hdparm -i /dev/sdb

```
/dev/sdb:

 Model=ST1000DM003-1SB102, FwRev=CC43, SerialNo=Z9A4EEL4
 Config={ HardSect NotMFM HdSw>15uSec Fixed DTR>10Mbs RotSpdTol>.5% }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=0
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=unknown, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=off
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=1953525168
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
 PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
 DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
 UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
 AdvancedPM=yes: unknown setting WriteCache=enabled
 Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-4,5,6,7
```

// dmesg | grep SATA

```
[    2.074207] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xfe00 ctl 0xfe10 bmdma 0xfea0 irq 18
[    2.080635] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xfe20 ctl 0xfe30 bmdma 0xfea8 irq 18
```

// lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82875P/E7210 Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82875P Processor to AGP Controller (rev 02)
00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82875P/E7210 Processor to I/O Memory Interface (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801EB (ICH5) SATA Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rage XL PCI (rev 27)
02:0c.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

// SATA version

```
// smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
```

Comment: I too get max speeds < 50 M/s on similar hardware.  Very interested in how to get closer to the 3-6 G/s speeds advertised on the HD.

Comment: @jc__ I'd be interested to know what you've tried and what effect it may have had if you had the time to summarize

Comment: *What file system are you writing to?* I have found that linux file systems are managed in a better way by linux than NTFS and therefore the write speed is much higher. *Is the file system encrypted?*

Comment: Please note that you are using UDMA6 right now, which has a transfer rate of 133 MB/sec, and that the max sustained transfer rate for your disk is 210 MB/s [https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/3-5-barracuda-3tbDS1900-10-1710US-en_US.pdf](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/3-5-barracuda-3tbDS1900-10-1710US-en_US.pdf)

Comment: @sudodus Not encrypted  and it's ext4

Comment: Also do a *performance test*. Use gnome-disks or dd, and write a large file (3xRAM for instance). rsync spends a lot of time comparing files, not only transfering!

Comment: If I had to *make a guess* (which I will) I would guess that both drives are connected to a single bus in the physical system - the bus is capable of speeds of 133 MB/s, but since two drives are sharing the bus, the perceived speed will be half of that as the drives share the bandwidth.  Then you add the overhead of rsync...  I run rsync to a USBc device, and see speeds of 100 MB/s for large file transfers

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks again I've included the output of `lspci`, `dmesg | grep SATA` and `smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep SATA` for reference

Comment: [An answer with some more advices](https://askubuntu.com/a/2101/266507).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this question might attract many different answers.

Out of top of my head, one trick is to save some writes by disabling `atime`. It's the time of last access to a file, by default it's usually set to `relatime`, which is better in terms of performance than `atime`. But, you can further improve it by disabling completely through `noatime` option. E.g.:

```
$ grep noatime /etc/fstab                  
UUID=9b5e4b95-46b1-4f54-aa07-9de91e01cbf2 /             ext4            rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks: for records i mounted the drive with `noatime` using the following `mount -o remount,noatime /dev/sdb2 /mnt`. I tried editing `/etc/fstab` as above and using my UUID but it didn't work.

Comment: To add it appears to have made a slight increase in speed to `±30Mb/s`